# Why is isNaN(null) == false in JS?

Tags: javascript

This code in JS gives me a popup saying "i think null is a number", which I find slightly disturbing. What am I missing?

```js
if (isNaN(null)) {
  alert("null is not a number");
} else {
  alert("i think null is a number");
}
```

I'm using Firefox 3. Is that a browser bug?

Other tests:

```js
console.log(null == NaN);   // false
console.log(isNaN("text")); // true
console.log(NaN == "text"); // false
```

So, the problem seems not to be an exact comparison with NaN?

***Edit:** Now the question has been answered, I have cleaned up my post to have a better version for the archive. However, this renders some comments and even some answers a little incomprehensible. Don't blame their authors. Among the things I changed was:*

- Removed a note saying that I had screwed up the headline in the first place by reverting its meaning
- Earlier answers showed that I didn't state clearly enough why I thought the behaviour was weird, so I added the examples that check a string and do a manual comparison.

Comment: don't you mean "Why is isNaN(null) == false" ?

Comment: Based on your code, isnan(null) is returning false (null is not "not a number") if it says "I think null is a number".

Comment: Use [`Number.isNaN`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) instead.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I believe the code is trying to ask, "is `x` numeric?" with the specific case here of `x = null`.  The function `isNaN()` can be used to answer this question, but semantically it's referring specifically to the value `NaN`. From Wikipedia for [`NaN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN):

> NaN (**N**ot **a** **N**umber) is a value of the numeric data type representing an undefined or unrepresentable value, especially in floating-point calculations.

In most cases we think the answer to "is null numeric?" should be no. However, `isNaN(null) == false` is semantically correct, because `null` is not `NaN`.

Here's the algorithmic explanation:

The function `isNaN(x)` attempts to convert the passed parameter to a number<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)</sup> (equivalent to `Number(x)`) and then tests if the value is `NaN`. If the parameter can't be converted to a number, `Number(x)` will return `NaN`<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)</sup>. Therefore, if the conversion of parameter `x` to a number results in `NaN`, it returns true; otherwise, it returns false.

So in the specific case `x = null`, `null` is converted to the number 0, (try evaluating `Number(null)` and see that it returns 0,) and `isNaN(0)` returns false. A string that is only digits can be converted to a number and isNaN also returns false. A string (e.g. `'abcd'`) that cannot be converted to a number will cause `isNaN('abcd')` to return true, specifically because `Number('abcd')` returns `NaN`.

In addition to these apparent edge cases are the standard numerical reasons for returning NaN like 0/0.

As for the seemingly inconsistent tests for equality shown in the question, the behavior of `NaN` is specified such that any comparison `x == NaN` is false, regardless of the other operand, including `NaN` itself<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)</sup>.

Comment: BTW, `NaN !== NaN`.

So, I think, it is not totally correct to say `Number('abcd') == NaN` because `Number('abcd')` is `NaN` but not equal to `NaN`.

I adore JavaScript.

Comment: Yes. I meant to convey that `Number('abcd')` is `NaN` but I implied that it tests true for equality, which is not the case. I will edit it.

Comment: I wonder why are `isNaN` and `Number` designed to behave that way?

Comment: The simple answer is that it's designed to have the same semantics as the IEEE 754 floating-point standard.

Comment: Since `null` is converted to `0`, why `null == false` returns false?

Comment: The conversion of `null` to `0` only (at least in this context) occurs within the `isNaN()` function, which coerces its argument.

Comment: Number(null) == 0 but parseInt(null) == NaN love JS

Comment: Note that `isNaN(undefined) === true`.

Comment: @JoshBerke `parseInt` accepts strings; `String(null)` is `"null"`, which doesn’t start with digits or whitespace followed by digits. `parseInt` and `Number` are very different functions.

Comment: To put simply - because +null = 0, therefore isNaN(null) = false.

Answer (score 41):

I just ran into this issue myself.

For me, the best way to use isNaN is like so

`isNaN(parseInt(myInt))`

taking phyzome's example from above,

```
var x = [undefined, NaN,     'blah', 0/0,  null, 0,     '0',   1,     1/0, -1/0,  Number(5)]
x.map( function(n){ return isNaN(parseInt(n))})
        [true,      true,    true,   true, true, false, false, false, true, true, false]
```

( I aligned the result according to the input, hope it makes it easier to read. )

This seems better to me.

Comment: Won't work if `myInt`="123d". `parseInt` converts "123d" to 123, which then fails the `isNaN` test.

Comment: indeed,  If you want to catch that scenario as well, I suggest to combine my answer and Glenn's. which will look like this `isNaN(parseInt(str,10)) || isNaN(Number())`. btw - for me, since I have to run `parseInt` in order to use the numeric value of the string, allowing "123d" to be considered as valid number is fine. However I see the need to detect that scenario as well.

Comment: And with the beauty if Typescript, you have to do isNaN(parseInt(String(myInt)))  

Answer (score 11):

This is indeed disturbing. Here is an array of values that I tested:

```
var x = [undefined, NaN, 'blah', 0/0, null, 0, '0', 1, 1/0, -1/0, Number(5)]
```

It evaluates (in the Firebug console) to:

```
,NaN,blah,NaN,,0,0,1,Infinity,-Infinity,5
```

When I call `x.map(isNaN)` (to call isNaN on each value), I get:

```
true,true,true,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false
```

In conclusion, `isNaN` looks pretty useless! (**Edit**: Except it turns out isNaN is only *defined* over Number, in which case it works just fine -- just with a misleading name.)

Incidentally, here are the types of those values:

```
x.map(function(n){return typeof n})
-> undefined,number,string,number,object,number,string,number,number,number,number
```

Comment: What do you imagine that NaN should mean?
What do you think is so misleading about NaN  or in testing for it?
Why are you disturbed?

Comment: Well, this was 8 years ago, but it looks like it I was disturbed that 1) it has inconsistent results for values that aren't of type Number, and 2) it ever returns true for something that isn't of type Number. Because a string is not, in fact, a NaN. (Also see my other answer, which explains why this happens.)

Answer (score 11):

(My other comment takes a practical approach. Here's the theoretical side.)

I looked up the [ECMA 262 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), which is what Javascript implements. Their specification for isNan:

> Applies ToNumber to its argument, then returns true if the result is NaN, and otherwise returns false.

Section 9.3 specifies the behavior of `ToNumber` (which is not a callable function, but rather a component of the type conversion system). To summarize the table, certain input types can produce a NaN. These are type `undefined`, type `number` (but only the value `NaN`), any object whose primitive representation is `NaN`, and any `string` that cannot be parsed. This leaves `undefined`, `NaN`, `new Number(NaN)`, and most strings.

Any such input that produces `NaN` as an output when passed to `ToNumber` will produce a `true` when fed to `isNaN`. Since `null` can successfully be converted to a number, it does not produce `true`.

And that is why.

Answer (score 4):

Null is not NaN, as well as a string is not NaN. isNaN() just test if you really have the NaN object.

Comment: But then at least a string is cast into a NaN object, as isNaN("text") returns true.

Comment: _“isNaN() just test if you really have the NaN object”_ — No, [`Number.isNaN`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) does that. `isNaN` coerces its argument to a number, _then_ checks if it is a `NaN` value.

Answer (score 3):

In ES5, it defined as `isNaN (number)` returns true if the argument coerces to NaN, and otherwise returns false.

- If [ToNumber(number)](https://es5.github.io/#x9.3) is NaN, return true.
- Otherwise, return false.

And see the [The abstract operation ToNumber convertion table](https://es5.github.io/#x9.3). So it internally js engine evaluate `ToNumber(Null)` is `+0`, then eventually `isNaN(null)` is `false`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure when it comes to JS but I've seen similar things in other languages and it's usually because the function is only checking whether null is exactly equal to NaN (i.e. null === NaN would be false). In other words it's not that it thinks that null is in fact a number, but it's rather that null is not NaN. This is probably because both are represented differently in JS so that they won't be exactly equal, in the same way that 9 !== '9'.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check for null, undefined, 0, '0', etc is using

```
isNaN(parseFloat(value))
```

as follows:

```js
const data = [null, undefined, NaN, 0, '0', false, true, 1, 3.14];

const result = data.map(value => isNaN(parseFloat(value)));

console.log('Result: ', result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Note:

```
"1" == 1 // true
"1" === 1 // false
```

The == operator does type-conversion, while === does not.

[Douglas Crockford's website](http://crockford.com/), a Yahoo! JavaScript evangelist, is a great resource for stuff like this.

Answer (score -2):

```
(NaN == null) // false
(NaN != null) // true
```

Funny though:

```
(NaN == true)  // false
(NaN == false) // false
(NaN)          // false
(!NaN)         // true
```

Aren't `(NaN == false)` and `(!NaN)` identical?