# Why does isNaN(" ") (string with spaces) equal false?

Tags: javascript, nan

In JavaScript, why does `isNaN("   ")` evaluate to `false`, but `isNaN("  x")` evaluate to `true`?

I’m performing numerical operations on a text input field, and I’m checking if the field is `null`, `""`, or `NaN`. When someone types a handful of spaces into the field, my validation fails on all three, and I’m confused as to why it gets past the `isNaN` check.

Comment: Hm... not quite sure where the other half of the subject went.  It's supposed to read, "JavaScript: Why does isNaN("   ") evaluate to false?"

Comment: Jes, that's the behavior (empty or space returns false for isNaN), but I didn't find the exact specs of this function.

Comment: Here's a question which answers this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115548/why-is-isnannull-false-in-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115548/why-is-isnannull-false-in-js)

Comment: Javascript on these issues seems like voodoo! You never know and the explanation is always quite complex. `"" == false // true` and `isNaN(" ") // false`

Comment: Use [`Number.isNaN`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) instead.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

JavaScript interprets an empty string as a 0, which then fails the isNAN test. You can use parseInt on the string first which won't convert the empty string to 0. The result should then fail isNAN.

Comment: But parseInt("123abcd") returns 123, which means isNaN(parseInt("123abcd")) will return false while it should return true!

Comment: So how about (IsNaN(string) || isNaN(parseInt(string)))

Comment: There's 2 steps in interpreting `isNaN(arg)`.  1) Convert arg to number, 2) Check if that number is the numerical value `NaN`.  That helped me understand it better.

Comment: @Antonio_Haley Wait a minute, I don't get it. If "JavaScript interprets an empty string as a 0", why does parseInt("") return NaN?

Comment: @Jean-François You're right, the more correct statement would be "isNaN interprets an empty string as 0", not JavaScript itself.

Comment: How about a separate empty string check: isNaN(value) || value === ''

Also seems to be more performant: http://jsperf.com/empty-string-is-nan

Comment: The string isn't empty though. It's a string of whitespace.

Comment: @Pawan Nogariya  parseInt  is for grabbing the number part off the start of a string  which in the case of "123abcd" is 123 so you got an actual number being returned. so while "123abcd" by itself would be NaN parseInt("123abcd") is not NaN as that function call does indeed return a number so thus why it returns false as 123 is a number.

Comment: @matt is right, except it should be `&&` instead of `||`: `(isNaN(string) && isNaN(parseInt(string)))`

Comment: Great answer.  I had the same problem of a number input always returning `false` when I entered a string or number e.g. `isNaN(2j) && isNaN("") && isNaN(2) //gave result as false` with `oninput` function.  I fixed this with your answer by first parsing the elements' value to `float` or `integer` before entering the value to be validated as attribute to `isNaN()` function.

Comment: And the terrible thing is, `isNaN(parseFloat("")) != isNaN("")`. `parseFloat("")` returns NaN but `isNaN("")` still says false!!

Answer (score 90):

You may find this surprising or maybe not, but here is some test code to show you the wackyness of the JavaScript engine.

```
document.write(isNaN("")) // false
document.write(isNaN(" "))  // false
document.write(isNaN(0))  // false
document.write(isNaN(null)) // false
document.write(isNaN(false))  // false
document.write("" == false)  // true
document.write("" == 0)  // true
document.write(" " == 0)  // true
document.write(" " == false)  // true
document.write(0 == false) // true
document.write(" " == "") // false
```

so this means that

```
" " == 0 == false
```

and

```
"" == 0 == false
```

but

```
"" != " "
```

Have fun :)

Comment: +1 Great post.  Can you add how the triple equals (=== and !==) operator fits here?

Comment: You should try NaN===NaN or NaN==NaN;-) I don't know if all this means the javascript engine is wacky or that javascript is bad for wacky programmers though.

Comment: @Kooilnc the fact that NaN != NaN is, actually, a good choice for once. The idea is that NaN is almost always a result of a computation that went different than how the programmer intended, and to assume that the results of two computations that went "wrong" are equal is pretty dangerous, I'd say.

Comment: @Kooilnc not to take away even slightly from the wackiness of javascript, but these NaNs are just obeying the IEEE 754 floating point standard. You can read ALL about it as usual on the big W: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: @NickBerardi F'ing LOL! I'm sooo glad I saw this post. Helped me figure out why the isNaN function is so retarded. I will be stripping it from my not-fully-developed code right now, and will likely never use it again. I will validate for `null`, `""`, and `" "` myself.  Thanks!

Comment: Great post but doesn't explain "why".

Comment: And that is why you should (almost) always use `===`.

Comment: what's really whacky is what follows: `" " == false` evaluates to true, BUT `" " || false` evaluates to `" "`.

Comment: Abstract equality is irrelevant here. `isNaN` performs _ToNumber_ of its argument, which means that `isNaN(arg)` and `isNaN(Number(arg))` are equivalent. @VoidKing If you want an `isNaN` that doesn’t perform this coercion, use `Number.isNaN`.

Answer (score 20):

To understand it better, please open [Ecma-Script spec pdf](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) on page 43 "ToNumber Applied to the String Type"

if a string has a numerical syntax, which can contain any number of white-space characters, it can be converted to Number type. Empty string evaluates to 0. Also the string 'Infinity' should give

```
isNaN('Infinity'); // false
```

Answer (score 13):

Try using:

```
alert(isNaN(parseInt("   ")));
```

Or

```
alert(isNaN(parseFloat("    ")));
```

Comment: hi sir, 

isNaN(parseInt("123a")) : will return 123  

so ur solution will not work , if the string contains aplha numeric

Answer (score 7):

From [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) reason for the issue you are facing

> When the argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is NaN.

You may want to check the following comprehensive answer which covers the NaN comparison for equality as well.

> [How to test if a JavaScript variable is `NaN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912757/893612)

Answer (score 6):

I think it's because of Javascript's typing: `' '` is converted to zero, whereas `'x'` isn't:

```
alert(' ' * 1); // 0
alert('x' * 1); // NaN
```

Answer (score 6):

#### The Not-Entirely-Correct Answer

Antonio Haley's [highly upvoted and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/825430/1317805) here makes a wrong assumption that this process goes through JavaScript's `parseInt` function:

> You can use parseInt on the string ... The result should then fail isNAN.

We can easily disprove this statement with the string `"123abc"`:

```js
parseInt("123abc")    // 123     (a number...
isNaN("123abc")       // true     ...which is not a number)
```

With this, we can see that JavaScript's `parseInt` function returns `"123abc"` as the number `123`, yet its `isNaN` function tells us that `"123abc"` *isn't* a number.

#### The Correct Answer

ECMAScript-262 defines how the `isNaN` check works in [section 18.2.3](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number).

> ## 18.2.3 `isNaN` (Number)
>
> The `isNaN` function is the `%isNaN%` intrinsic object. When the `isNaN` function is called with one argument number, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let `num` be ? `ToNumber(number)`.
> 2. If `num` is `NaN`, return `true`.
> 3. Otherwise, return `false`.

The `ToNumber` function it references is also defined in [ECMAScript-262's section 7.1.3](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tonumber). In here, we get told how JavaScript handles Strings which are passed in to this function.

The first example given in the question is a string containing nothing but white space characters. This section states that:

> A `StringNumericLiteral` that is empty or contains only white space is converted to `+0`.

The `"   "` example string is therefore converted to `+0`, which is a number.

The same section also states:

> If the grammar cannot interpret the `String` as an expansion of `StringNumericLiteral`, then the result of `ToNumber` is `NaN`.

Without quoting all of the checks contained within that section, the `"  x"` example given in the question falls into the above condition as it cannot be interpreted as a `StringNumericLiteral`. `"  x"` is therefore converted to `NaN`.

Answer (score 4):

The function `isNaN("")` performs a **String to Number *type coercion***

[ECMAScript 3-5 defines the following return values for the typeof operator:](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)

- undefined
- object (null, objects, arrays)
- boolean
- number
- string
- function

Better to wrap our test in a function body:

```
function isNumber (s) {
    return typeof s == 'number'? true
           : typeof s == 'string'? (s.trim() === ''? false : !isNaN(s))
           : (typeof s).match(/object|function/)? false
           : !isNaN(s)
}
```

This function is not intented to test variable *type*, instead it tests the *coerced value*. For instance, booleans and strings are coerced to numbers, so perhaps you may want to call this function as `isNumberCoerced()`

if there's no need to test for *types* other than *string* and *number*, then the following snippet might be used as part of some condition:

```
if (!isNaN(s) && s.toString().trim()!='') // 's' can be boolean, number or string
    alert("s is a number")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to implement an accurate isNumber function, here is one way to do it from *Javascript: The Good Parts* by Douglas Crockford [page 105]

```
var isNumber = function isNumber(value) {
   return typeof value === 'number' && 
   isFinite(value);
}
```

Comment: @Xyan in which case this function isn't very helpful to perform the task the OP was asking to do, which was to inspect a string representation of a number...

Comment: using the so called strict equality operator of any given value against a string literal such as "number" is stupid,

Answer (score 3):

`NaN` !== "not a number"

`NaN` is a value of Number Type

this is a definition of isNaN() in ECMAScript

```
1. Let num be ToNumber(number).
2. ReturnIfAbrupt(num).
3. If num is NaN, return true.
4. Otherwise, return false.
```

Try to convert any value to Number.

```
Number(" ") // 0
Number("x") // NaN
Number(null) // 0
```

If you want to determine if the value is `NaN`, you should try to convert it to a Number value firstly.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the following function if you really want a proper check if it is an integer:

```
function isInteger(s)
{
   return Math.ceil(s) == Math.floor(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That `isNaN(" ")` is false is part of the confusing behavior of the `isNaN` global function due to its coercion of non-numbers to a numeric type.

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Confusing_special-case_behavior)*:

> Since the very earliest versions of the `isNaN` function specification, its behavior for non-numeric arguments has been confusing. When the argument to the `isNaN` function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is `NaN`. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to numeric type result in a valid non-NaN numeric value (notably the empty string and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric values zero or one), the "false" returned value may be unexpected; the empty string, for example, is surely "not a number."

Note also that with ECMAScript 6, there is also now the `Number.isNaN` method, which according to MDN:

> In comparison to the global `isNaN()` function, `Number.isNaN()` doesn't suffer the problem of forcefully converting the parameter to a number. This means it is now safe to pass values that would normally convert to `NaN`, but aren't actually the same value as `NaN`. This also means that only values of the type number, that are also `NaN`, return `true`.

**Unfortunately**:

Even the ECMAScript 6 `Number.isNaN` method has its own issues, as outlined in the blog post - [Fixing the ugly JavaScript and ES6 NaN problem](http://lucono.com/post/117486285002/fixing-the-ugly-javascript-and-es6-nan-problem).

Comment: That blog post mentions boxed numbers as a problem. [No one should use boxed numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41458001/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

The `isNaN` function expects a Number as its argument, so arguments of any other type (in your case a string) will be converted to Number *before* the actual function logic is performed. (Be aware that `NaN` is also a value of type Number!)

Btw. this is common for *all* built-in functions - if they expect an argument of a certain type, the actual argument will be converted using the standard conversion functions. There are standard conversions between all the basic types (bool, string, number, object, date, null, undefined.)

The standard conversion for `String` to `Number` can be invoked explicit with `Number()`. So we can see that:

- `Number("   ")` evaluates to `0`
- `Number("   x")` evaluates to `NaN`

Given this, the result of the `isNaN` function is completely logical!

The real question is why the standard String-to-Number conversion works like it does. The string-to-number conversion is really intended to convert numeric strings like "123" or "17.5e4" to the equivalent numbers. The conversion first skips initial whitespace (so " 123" is valid) and then tries to parse the rests as a number. If it is not parseable as a number ("x" isn't) then the result is NaN. But there is the explicit special rule that a string which is empty or only whitespace is converted to 0. So this explains the conversion.

Reference: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *why*, but to get around the problem you could always trim whitespace before checking.  You probably want to do that anyway.

Comment: a trimmed empty string also fails isNaN test.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this quick little function to help solve this problem.

```
function isNumber(val) {
     return (val != undefined && val != null && val.toString().length > 0 && val.toString().match(/[^0-9\.\-]/g) == null);
};
```

It simply checks for any characters that aren't numeric (0-9), that aren't '-' or '.', and that aren't undefined, null or empty  and returns true if there's no matches. :)

Comment: A belated thank you for this; this solved my problem very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

As other explained the `isNaN` function will coerce the empty string into a number before validating it, thus changing an empty string into 0 (which is a valid number).
However, I found that the `parseInt` function will return `NaN` when trying to parse an empty string or a string with only spaces. As such the following combination seems to be working well:

`if ( isNaN(string) || isNaN(parseInt(string)) ) console.log('Not a number!');`

This check will work for positive numbers, negative numbers and numbers with a decimal point, so I believe it covers all common numerical cases.

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```js
    function isNotANumeric(val) {
     if(val.trim && val.trim() == "") {
         return true;
      } else {
        return isNaN(parseFloat(val * 1));
      }
    }
    
    alert(isNotANumeric("100"));  // false
    alert(isNotANumeric("1a"));   // true
    alert(isNotANumeric(""));     // true
    alert(isNotANumeric("   "));  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

This function seemed to work in my tests

```
function isNumber(s) {
    if (s === "" || s === null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var number = parseInt(s);
        if (number == 'NaN') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your whole function can be written: `return !(s === "" || s === null || parseInt(s) == 'NaN');`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
function isNumberRegex(value) {        
    var pattern = /^[-+]?\d*\.?\d*$/i;
    var match = value.match(pattern);
    return value.length > 0 && match != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***JavaScript*** built-in **isNaN** function, is - as should be expected by default - a "Dynamic Type Operator".
Therefore all values which (during the DTC process) may yield a simple true | false such as `"", "  ", "   000"`, cannot be NaN.

Meaning that the *argument* supplied will first undergo a *conversion* as in:

```
function isNaNDemo(arg){
   var x = new Number(arg).valueOf();
   return x != x;
}
```

**Explanation:**

In the top line of the function body, we are (first) trying to successfully convert the argument into a number object. And (second), using the dot operator we are - for our own convenience - immediately stripping off, *the **primitive** value* of the created object.

In the second line, we are taking the value obtained in the previous step, and the advantage of the fact that ***NaN*** is not equal to anything in the universe, not even to itself, e.g.: `NaN == NaN >> false` to finally compare it (for inequality) with itself.

This way the function return will yield ***true*** only when, and only if, the supplied argument-return, is a failed attempt of conversion to a number object, i.e., a not-a-number number; e.g., NaN.

---

***isNaNstatic( )***

However, for a Static Type Operator - if needed and when needed - we can write a far simpler function such as:

```
function isNaNstatic(x){   
   return x != x;
}
```

And avoid the DTC altogether so that if the argument is not explicitly a NaN number, it will return false. Wherefore, testing against the following:

`isNaNStatic("   x"); // will return false` because it's still a string.

However:
`isNaNStatic(1/"x"); // will of course return true.` as will for instance `isNaNStatic(NaN); >> true`.

But contrary to `isNaN`, the `isNaNStatic("NaN"); >> false` because it (the argument) is an ordinary string.

p.s.:
The static version of isNaN can be very useful in modern coding scenarios. And it may very well be one of the main reasons I took my time for posting this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`isNAN(<argument>)` is a function to tell whether given argument is illegal number.
`isNaN` typecasts the arguments into Number type. If you want to check if argument is Numeric or not? Please use `$.isNumeric()` function in jQuery.

That is, isNaN(foo) is equivalent to isNaN(Number(foo))
It accepts any strings having all numerals as numbers for obvious reasons. For ex.

```
isNaN(123) //false
isNaN(-1.23) //false
isNaN(5-2) //false
isNaN(0) //false
isNaN('123') //false
isNaN('Hello') //true
isNaN('2005/12/12') //true
isNaN('') //false
isNaN(true) //false
isNaN(undefined) //true
isNaN('NaN') //true
isNaN(NaN) //true
isNaN(0 / 0) //true
```

Answer (score 0):

When checking if certain string value with whitespace or `" "`is `isNaN` maybe try to perform string validation, example :

`// value = "123 "
if (value.match(/\s/) || isNaN(value)) {
   // do something
}`

Answer (score 0):

I find it convenient to have a method specific to the Number class (since other functions that do conversions like parseInt have different outputs for some of these values) and use prototypal inheritance.

```
Object.assign(Number.prototype, {
  isNumericallyValid(num) {
    if (
      num === null
      || typeof num === 'boolean'
      || num === ''
      || Number.isNaN(Number(num))
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following.

`x=(isNaN(parseFloat(x)))? 0.00 : parseFloat(x);`

Answer (score -1):

```js
let isNotNumber = val => isNaN(val) || (val.trim && val.trim() === '');

console.log(isNotNumber(' '));
console.log(isNotNumber('1'));
console.log(isNotNumber('123x'));
console.log(isNotNumber('x123'));
console.log(isNotNumber('0'));
console.log(isNotNumber(3));
console.log(isNotNumber('    x'));
console.log(isNotNumber('1.23'));
console.log(isNotNumber('1.23.1.3'));

if(!isNotNumber(3)){
  console.log('This is a number');
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question and appears to be a vaguely random code snippet with no explanation provided.