# isNaN() vs. parseInt() confusion

Tags: javascript

There is something strange.

Why
with `isNaN("")` I get `False`
But
with `parseInt("")` I get `NaN`
?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-equal-false

Comment: Because `isNaN` doesn't use `parseInt`?

Comment: The key is to understand the difference between **type conversion** and **parsing**, `isNaN` behind the scenes, will do type conversion of its argument to the `Number` type, while `parseInt` will try to *parse* the string provided. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does isNaN(" ") (string with spaces) equal false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-string-with-spaces-equal-false)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`isNaN` takes an integer as an argument - therefore JS converts `""` to `0`

`parseInt` takes a string as an argument - therefore an empty string is not a number

Comment: already answered - duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-equal-false

Comment: `isNaN` doesn't take an "integer", it *expects* a Number (which are all IEEE-754 doubles, e.g. `isNaN(0.5)` yields `false`), that's why it tries to *type convert* the argument value to Number

Answer (score 1):

This is because `""` is equivalent to zero in JavaScript.  Try `"" == 0`.  This means if you try evaluating it in a numerical equation, it will come up as 0.  When you parse it on the other hand it realizes there is nothing there.

As an alternative to `parseInt` you could use `Math.floor`.  This will give you `0` for `""`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is equivalent"?