# parseInt doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my current source code textbox value is 1. 
when I try `alert(isNaN(obj.text())` it returns `false` that is expected but after parseInt when I write `alert(a);` it returns `NaN`

```
minus.click(function () {
     var a = 1; if (!isNaN(obj.text())) a = parseInt(obj.text()); 
     if (a > 1) a -= 1; obj.text(a);
});
```

what is the problem?

Edit: this is the full code:

```
<input type="text" class="basket-txt" value="1" />


jQuery.fn.basket = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
    }
    options = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
    this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.height(32).css({ 'line-height': '32px', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'width':'40px', 'text-align':'center', });
        var tbl = $('<table border="0" style="border-spacing:0px;float:left;">').appendTo($this.parent());
        var tr1 = $('<tr>').appendTo(tbl);
        var plus = $('<div class="basket-plus">');
        $('<td>').append(plus).appendTo(tr1);
        $('<td>').append($this).appendTo(tr1);
        var minus = $('<div class="basket-minus">');
        $('<td>').append(minus).appendTo(tr1);
        var tr2 = $('<tr>').appendTo(tbl);
        $('<td>').appendTo(tr2);
        $('<td>').appendTo(tr2).append($('<div>').addClass('add-to-basket'));
        $('<td>').appendTo(tr2);
        $this.keypress(function (e) { if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) e.preventDefault(); });
        minus.click(function () {

            var a = 1; if (!isNaN($this.text())) a = parseInt($this.text()); 
            if (a > 1) a -= 1; $this.text(a);
        });
        plus.click(function () {
            var a = 1; if (!isNaN($this.text())) a = parseInt($this.text());
            if (a < 1000000) a += 1; $this.text(a);
        });
    });
}
```

**actually I knew I could correct the code and it would work my concern was to understand why isNaN returns false but parseInt returns NaN**

Comment: What exactly is the string value of `obj.text()`? Is it really just "1" or are there other characters?

Comment: I pasted the full code

Comment: You realize that `if (false) console.log("no"); console.log("yes");` will still print out `"yes"` don't you?

Comment: (a side note: whenever you parseInt, add the radix: parseInt(str, 10), older JavaScript will surprise you otherwise)

Comment: @NicoSantangelo yes, I know, but as isNaN is false parseInt should work and after parse int a should have a value and not NaN

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani you're making an incorrect assumption about what the `isNaN()` function does.

Comment: The problem is clearly with `obj.text()` otherwise it would work. You are probably sending isNaN an empty string. The function isNaN doesn't always do the right thing, e.g., `isNaN('') === false` Try parsing your integer **first**, then checking if it's NaN or not. Also, use `obj.val()` instead.

Comment: oh I got it when the return value is "" isNaN returns true but parseInt fails

Comment: No, isNaN will return false for `""` which makes your code think it's a number but it isn't. You should re-write your code. Use `obj.val()`

Comment: I edited my question. You asked why isNaN returns false and parseInt returns NaN, check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271836/isnan-vs-parseint-confusion) and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-equal-false)

Comment: Let this question serve to readers that you must be **clear** in your question to get the answer you want. If you fear being misunderstood, add as much information as possible; too much is better than too little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
minus.click(function () {
    // let's parse the integer first
     var num = parseInt( obj.val(), 10 );

     // then later, we can check if it's NaN
     if ( !isNaN(num) && num > 1 ) {
        num -= 1;
        obj.val(num);
     }
});
```

---

> actually I knew I could correct the code and it would work my concern was
>   to understand why isNaN returns false but parseInt returns NaN

*isNaN* doesn't work the way it should. There is type coercion going on.
*isNaN* will convert the value to a number first. An empty string will be converted to a `0`

```
Number("") === 0; // true
```

`0` is obviously not NaN, so it returns false.

*parseInt* doesn't do type coercion, it parses the value differently.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271836/isnan-vs-parseint-confusion) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-equal-false) for reference.

Answer (score 5):

You get the value of an `<input>` with `.val()`, not `.text()`.

The `isNaN()` function returns `false` for `isNaN("")`. Why? Because when `""` (the empty string) is converted to a number, it's `0`. Pass a non-number to `isNaN()` and the first thing it does is coerce the value into a number.

It's kind-of pointless to try `isNaN()` before `parseInt()` anyway, since `parseInt()` will tell you when it can't parse a nice-looking integer.  Note however that `parseInt()` doesn't care if there's garbage at the *end* of the input.

If you want to convert a string to a number when it's a valid string representation of a number, and `NaN` when it isn't, you can use

```
var myNumber = +myString;
```

That'll accept numbers with fractional parts and exponents too, so you'd have to either truncate that to just an integer or check to see if it is one:

```
var myNumber = +myString;
if (isNaN(myNumber))
  // not a valid number
else if (myNumber !== Math.floor(myNumber))
  // not an integer
else
  // yaay!
```

Answer (score 5):

The jQuery `text()` method will take all the descendent text nodes of an element and combine them into a single string.

An `input` element can't have descendant nodes of any kind. Its current value is exposed via the `value` property, which you can read with the `val()` method in jQuery.

You shouldn't use `parseInt` without a radix, especially with free form input. You might get octal or hex data instead of a decimal.

```
parseInt($this.val(), 10)
```

Comment: well what i'm really trying to understand that why isNaN($this.text()) is false but parseInt value is NaN. I'm just trying to understand this.

Comment: I just told you why in the main comments. `isNaN` doesn't work the way it should. If you send isNaN an empty string, or a string of spaces, it will return false even though it shouldn't.

Comment: `isNaN('') === false; // false`

Answer (score 0):

parseInt returns NaN when the first non-whitespace character cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).