# What is "" in JavaScript really?

Tags: javascript

This one says `false`, meaning the `""` is a number:

```
alert(isNaN(""));
```

This one says `NaN`, meaning the `""` is not a number and cannot be converted:

```
alert(parseFloat(""));
```

I was expecting the second code to convert `""` to `0` since `""` is a number when tested in `IsNaN` but I was wrong! Am I getting crazy or I just missed something?

Comment: `""` is a string.

Comment: Hmm that is interesting. "" is just going to be an empty string though. Basically you just proved that isNaaN does not use the same code that parseFloat does

Comment: @isbadawi Thanks, I edited my question so you'll understand what I really want to achieve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-equal-false

Comment: [MDN's isNaN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) starts out with a warning, "Be careful, this function is broken." It goes on to explain why (and mentions the empty string explicitly).

Comment: I wonder why Mozilla uses IEEE 794 and not IEEE 754... (does the former even exist?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseFloat` tries to parse a number from string where as `isNaN` [converts the argument to number](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4) before checking it:

```
Number("") //0 http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1
parseFloat("") //NaN http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3
```

Apparently this is "broken" or "confusing", so from the specs:

> A reliable way for ECMAScript code to test if a value X is a NaN is an
>   expression of the form X !== X. The result will be true if and only if
>   X is a NaN.

```
0 !== 0 // false
NaN !== NaN //true

function isExactlyNaN(x) {
    return x !== x;
}
```

Comment: Side-note to confirm behavior: `isNaN("NaN")` returns `true`.

Comment: @leppie So does `isNaN("pepperoni")` :)

Comment: @PaulP.R.O.: Definitely IEEE 794 ;p

Answer (score 1):

`isNaN` converts to the Number type and checks if the value is the special number NaN.

The empty string converted to a number is `0` (`+"" === 0`), and since `0` isn't `NaN` you see `false`.

[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) however is more complicated than a simple conversion to the number type, and it returns `NaN` for the empty string (`parseFloat("") === NaN`).

Answer (score 1):

Being not `NaN` is not the same as being a number. It just means you aren't the very special value `NaN`.

<sub>Or anything convertible to `NaN` by the arcane conversion rules of the JS language.</sub>

Comment: What does "NaN" mean again? Not-a-Number right? Removing the "Not-a" makes it a number :D at least in my perception.

Comment: @dpp `NaN` is also a number: `typeof NaN === "number"`

Comment: `NaN` is a special number value. Perhaps it would be better to think of it as "the 'number' representing the result of operations like 0/0 or Infinity/Infinity"

Answer (score 0):

Javascript interprets empty string as 0 which fails isNaN test. As for parseFloat tries to parse the number in the empty string which fails and returns NaN..

Comment: Is it JavaScript that interprets it as a 0 or the isNaN function? Coz if it's JavaScript, then why parseFloat does not consider "" as 0?

Answer (score 0):

To understand behavior of this it's important to understand semantics.

`isNaN` checks whether value cannot be **coerced** to number, if calling it on value returns false, then it means that `Number(value)` will return valid number.

`parseFloat` **parses** number from a string, if string doesn't start with any number then it returns `NaN`, as no number to parse was found.

Programmers tend to overuse `parseInt` and `parseFloat` for coercion, when in most cases they should use `Number`, which is more strict and not that confusing.