# Calculation accepts space in input filds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script to calculate a form

```
    $(".mad, .mad2, .mad3, .mad4, .mad5, .mad6").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            antal += parseFloat(this.value);
             subtotal = antal*30;
             $(this).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        }
        else if (this.value.length != 0){
             $(this).css("background-color", "#e89898");
       }
    });
        $("#antal").html(antal.toFixed(0));
        $("#subtotal").html(subtotal.toFixed(0));
```

it seems to work fine, if one is trying to ad a letter or its being removed and the input field turns red. however i dos accept space resulting in the antal and subtotal Show NaN

How do i get it to work for both letters AND space (not accepting space either ) ?

Comment: just replace spaces by empty string: `this.value.replace(/ /g,'')`

Comment: why do you need the `if` in the `else if`? shouldn't this just be `else`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does isNaN(" ") equal false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-equal-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use jquery's trim() method to remove all the whitespaces:

```
if (this.value.trim().length != 0 && !isNaN(this.value.trim()) ) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks buth where in my script do i ad that

Comment: I assume you figured it out? You want to replace the first if statement that you posted with what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (parseFloat(this.value) == this.value) {
```