# Why is an Array with one Number a Number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I've found that an empty array or an arwith exactly one Number is a Number.

This topic is not really an explanation for this special case I think: [Why does isNaN(" ") equal false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-equal-false)

```
document.write( isNaN([1,2,3]) ); // true
document.write( isNaN([1,2,'abc']) ); // true
document.write( isNaN(['abc']) ); // true

// maybe explained through the above link
document.write( isNaN([]) ); // false

// but...
document.write( isNaN([1]) ); // false
document.write( isNaN([-3]) ); // false
document.write( isNaN([1234567]) ); // false
document.write( isNaN([-1.234]) ); // false
document.write( isNaN([[123]]) ); // false
document.write( isNaN(['1']) ); // false
```

Who can tell me why it makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isNaN` coerces its value to a number. ([See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN))

Because the string representation of an array is all of its items concatenated with a comma. And the numerical representation of that is `NaN` because of the comma.

But if there's only one item, hence no comma, it's able to be converted to a number.

Comment: Yeah, but how does that make sense?

Comment: @algorhythm check the [MDN: isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and the difference between the old global `isNaN()` and the `Number.isNaN()`

Comment: @algorhythm `isNaN`: "[Returns `true` if the argument coerces to `NaN`, and otherwise returns `false`.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4)" -- Here "coerces" means using the [`ToNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) abstract operation on the argument, which stringifies objects (like Arrays) and then number-ifies strings (like `"1234567"`, which is the stringified form of `[1234567]`). If the stringified form of the object has a comma (like `"1,2,3"`), then the string can't be sensibly converted to a number, so it's coerced to `NaN`.

Comment: Note that there is special case where if a string contains only whitespace, then *ToNumber* returns `0`, so `isNaN('\n')` returns false, while `isNaN('foo')` (or any other non–numeric string literal) returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `isNaN` global function which has some confusing behavior due to its coercion of non-numbers to a numeric type which can then result in the NaN value. This is what is happening in your case as the string representation of an array containing a single number element will successfully parse to the number value of the single number element.

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Confusing_special-case_behavior)*:

> Since the very earliest versions of the `isNaN` function specification, its behavior for non-numeric arguments has been confusing. When the argument to the `isNaN` function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is `NaN`. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to numeric type result in a valid non-NaN numeric value (notably the empty string and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric values zero or one), the "false" returned value may be unexpected; the empty string, for example, is surely "not a number."

Note also that with ECMAScript 6, there is also now the `Number.isNaN` method, which according to MDN:

> In comparison to the global `isNaN()` function, `Number.isNaN()` doesn't suffer the problem of forcefully converting the parameter to a number. This means it is now safe to pass values that would normally convert to `NaN`, but aren't actually the same value as `NaN`. This also means that only values of the type number, that are also `NaN`, return `true`.

**Unfortunately**:

Even the ECMAScript 6 `Number.isNaN` method has its own issues, as outlined in the blog post - [Fixing the ugly JavaScript and ES6 NaN problem](http://lucono.com/post/117486285002/fixing-the-ugly-javascript-and-es6-nan-problem).