# Delay in data/model update in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created an example which is similar to my current work.

```js
var App  = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    demoText:'text',
    sections:2,
    sectionData:[0,0]
  },
  methods:{
    changeData:function(){
      for(var i=0;i<this.sections;i++){
        if(isNaN(this.sectionData[i]))
          this.sectionData[i]=0;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  
  <div v-for="n in sections">
    <input type="text" v-model=sectionData[n-1]>
  </div>
  
  <input type="button" @click="changeData" value="click">
</div>
```

In this example, when I click on the button I check if data is `isNaN` and change it to zero if it is. But this updated data doesn't update in DOM/textbox immediately. After that, if I update in another textbox then pending update action happens.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in play here.

First is that [Vue cannot detect the change](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) you are making in your `click` handler when you change it by *index*. This is a common caveat when modifying an array in Vue.

Second, there is a bug in the code where if you blank out a text box, `isNaN("")` will resolve to `false`. This is [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-equal-false) in a number of places. I've implemented a very naive fix for this in the code below, but you should search for a stronger solution.

```js
var App  = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    demoText:'text',
    sections:2,
    sectionData:[0,0]
  },
  methods:{
    changeData:function(){
      this.sectionData = this.sectionData.map(d => isNaN(parseInt(d,10)) ? 0 : d)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  
  <div v-for="n in sections">
    <input type="text" v-model=sectionData[n-1]>
  </div>
  
  <input type="button" @click="changeData" value="click">
</div>
```

Another alternative implementation of your click handler would be

```
for (let i=0; i < this.sectionData.length; i++)
  if (isNaN(parseInt(this.sectionData[i],10)))
    this.sectionData.splice(i, 1, 0)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I didn't know about this caveat, and this isNaN was a just sample, my actual implementation has different functions, for simplicity I create like this.