# Why won't this code work on a string?

Tags: javascript

So i am practicing algorithms(javascript), and i come across this challenge, where we have to filter an array, remove the following elements:

false, NaN, undefined, "", null, 0

My code seems to have problems with strings and chars, it failed these tests.

-bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]) should return [7, "ate", 9]
*(returned [7, 9])*

-bouncer(["a", "b", "c"]) should return ["a", "b", "c"]
*(returned [])*

```
    function bouncer(arr) {
        return arr.filter(function(element)
                {
                    if (element != false && !isNaN(element) && element != null && element != "" && element != undefined)
                        {return element;}
                }
               );
    }
```

I would love a simple explanation of the concept i am missing

Comment: Use `!==` oprator, then it shoud work

Comment: You're falling into the JavaScript coercion problem. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/825402/215552) for more on how `isNaN` behaves on strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(element) {
            if (element) {
                return element;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Here is the answer for you.

Comment: Sure, the problem is !isNaN("ate"); will be false for all string and chars :)

Comment: No need for the `if` condition really. You could pretty much just return the element and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the given coercion propblem with `!=` instead of `!==`, you could filter by using `Boolean` as callback, which returns truthy elements.

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(Boolean);
}

console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9])); // [7, "ate", 9]
console.log(bouncer(["a", "b", "c"]));          // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Well this will fail in case of console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9, new Boolean(false)]));

Comment: @Gautam, an object instance is always truthy, despite of their `this` value.

Comment: Oh yes, thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for all the conditions. Please have a look at it.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(element) {
        if (element && element.trim().length > 0 && element != "NaN") {
            return element;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @vishwad - The code shared by Gautam doesn't check for 'NaN', so please keep a check for that as well in your code. Thanks!