# Can someone explain me this javascript behaviour? isNaN([])

Tags: javascript

I just don't get it:

```
isNaN([]) === false -> true
```

In the browser or in node.js

I'd like to understand why.

Comment: That's the answer I would expect; it seems intuitive.  Please explain what you think that result means and why you think it is confusing.

Comment: @SamHartman, "`[]` is a number", is intuitive?? You have a strange definition of the word

Comment: Because `isNaN([])` returns `false` and `false === false` is `true`.

Comment: `[]` is converted to `0`, and 0 is a number. `Number([]);`

Comment: it's coerced, not converted. there's a slight difference. In practice, conversion (`parseInt([])`) returns NaN

Comment: @smac89 `isNaN` tests whether *a number* is the special `NaN` value. Calling it on non-numbers is a misuse in the first place. But yes `[]` as a number is not `NaN`.

Comment: Closely related: [Why does `isNaN(" ")` equal false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/825402/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has to do with type coercion. when `isNaN` receives anything but a number, it coerces the value to a number... so it basically does `+value`. since `+[]` is `0` and `0` is a number, `isNaN` returns `false`.

If you want to check whether a value is not a number, you need to convert it with `parseInt` (or `parseFloat`). both those functions will return NaN for an empty array.

The difference is with conversion you're explicitly telling it the input is number-like and should therefore be able to be converted into a value of type `Number` without issues. Since `[]` is not number-like, trying to parse (convert) it will result in NaN.

**This is an extremely simplified explanation of how parsing and conversion work. For one, they are two separate things. if you want to learn more about how these two work, start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**

With coercion, however (which is what you're doing), you essentially passed it a value and "assumed" (for lack of a better word) the values type is compatible with the parameters' requirements. So isNaN receives an array and guesses you meant to pass it a number, and coerces it to its number equivalent (in the case of an empty array, 0) before performing the actual operation. so isNaN is performed on 0, not an empty array.

**Again, this explanation is oversimplified. for more information about type coercion in JS, go [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md)**

Comment: You mean `isNaN` returns `false` when it's a number.

Comment: thanks for pointing the mistake out... it's hard to wrap your head around JavaScript's idiosyncrasies sometimes

Comment: This answer is just wrong.  isNAN is not about determining if something is a number.

Comment: @SamHartman I never said that. I further explained how coercion works, in case you want to revisit your downvote

Answer (score 0):

[NAN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) is what is returned when a math function fails. NaN is present in almost all languages that do floating point math.  However some Javascript functions (and the internal logic that coerces values) also return NaN when values are coerced to being a number that do not have a numeric representation.  It's a lot easier to understand why `isNaN` is defined the way it is if you think about NaN as being intended for the case where your math gave a nonsense answer and ignore its role in representing numeric coersion failures.  Obviously when writing Javascript, you'll need to consider (and use) the coersion NaN, but this particular language design choice makes more sense if you ignore that for the moment.

So, for example `math.sqrt(-1)` is NAN.  the `isNAN` function returns true if and only if its input argument is NAN.  Since `[]` is not NAN, I'd expect `isNAN([])` to return false.  `isNAN` is the wrong function for determining if something is a number.  It does have strange coersion rules, buteven without them, the answer would be the same in the case  of `isNAN([]`.  `[]` is not the`NAN` object, so `isNAN([])` is false.  As @Nicolás Straub points out, the implementation happens to coerce `[]` to a number first, but we'd expect the same result given the interface contract of `isNAN` even if it did not.

```
ReferenceError: ISNAN is not defined
at repl:1:1
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:272:27)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:441:12)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:203:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:542:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:819:14)
```

> isNaN
>   [Function: isNaN]
>
> isNaN("bar")
>       true

However, `"bar"` is not actually the IEEE not a number floating point construct, so we'd expect  that a function would tell us `"bar"` is not `NaN`.  Because `isNaN` coerces its argument to a number, it gives us the wrong answer.
The es6  `Number.isNaN` function would give us the correct answer `"bar"` is not `NaN`.

Comment: Remember NaN is a Number (strange as it may seem), so the behaviour has everything to do with coercion

Comment: @Nicolás Straub they have everything to do with the implementation and nothing to do with the interface contract.  You want isNAN to return false for every object in the universe except for NAN.

Comment: OK, without getting into too much detail, let's first look at your example. Math.sqrt doesn't try to get the square root of a negative number, it does `if val < 0 return NaN`, so, internally, no mathematical operation was performed. If you do the same, but with `"1"`, the output is `1`, because the value put in is implicitly converted (coerced) to a number. In the case of the OP question `isNaN([])` returns false because, again, the array is coerced to a number. The process is as so: [].valueOf() is called, which returns an empty string, which is a native type. that, in turn, is converted

Comment: to a number explicitly (not exactly casting, but let's call it that), so the operation can be performed, because isNaN requires a number to operate. since casting an empty string to a number results in 0 in JS, isNaN returns false because it performs the operation against the number 0. if you use parseInt, it returns NaN because the first character of the array, converted via the toString method, is not a number, not because you didn't actually pass a number in. in fact, `parseInt([1,2,3])` results in 123, whereas `isNaN([1,2,3])` equals `true`. I won't continue to comment because of space

Comment: and BTW, I didn't downvote your answer because I don't agree with you, I did it because I find it incomplete to the point of being misleading.

Comment: @Nicolás Straub  I agree that my answer was incomplete to the point of being misleading.  I've expanded it significantly; thanks for the motivation to do so.

Comment: I removed the downvote. just want to say coercion is critical though. For example, `isNaN(parseInt([1,2,3]))` returns `false` but `isNaN([1,2,3])` returns `true`. This (and a ton of other gremlins in JS's type conversion approach) is why it's very important to have at least a basic understanding of how coercion works. Otherwise, you end up confused in a pit of code behaving extremely poorly, scratching your head and asking yourself 'Why??' (as the OP was). I've been there more times than I care to admit with this language, which is why I feel understanding coercion is so important