# Trigger alter on either textbox or dropdown value dont match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textbox and drop-down I want to compare both the values and trigger alert every time when something changes and both are not equal.
Suppose If I select six from my drop-down and If I don't enter 6 numbers in my textbox it should trigger alert and also I should get alert if I enter 6 numbers in textbox and select 12 numbers in my drop-down. How do I write single function to check both the conditions?

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myDropdown').change(function () {
            
             var sixNumeric = /^[0-9]{6}$/;
              var twelveNumeric = /^.[0-9]{12}$/;
              
             var dropdown = $("#myDropdown").val();
             var textval = $("#myInput").val();
            
            if (myDropdown == 'text' ) {
               alert("enter only text");
                   
                }
                if (dropdown == "six") {
                    if (sixNumeric.test(textval) ==false ) {
                        alert("Must be 6 numeric");
                    }
                } 
                if (dropdown == "tweleve") {
                    if (twelveNumeric.test(textval) ==false ) {
                        alert("Must be 12 numeric");
                    }
                } 
            });
```

```html
<select id="myDropdown">
    <option value="six">SixNumeric</option>
    <option value="tweleve">TwelveNumeric</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myInput"  value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dropdown` variable is not well defined. It refers to the value of `stateCode` where it should be referring to the dropdown value. If you change this line

```
var dropdown = $("#stateCode").val();
```

to

```
var dropdown = $("#myDropdown").val();
```

it should work.

You should also remove or change this part :

```
if (myDropdown == 'text' ) {
     alert("enter only text");
}
```

As `myDropdown` is not defined in your code.

Comment: Sorry! I made mistake while pasting my code. Edited my code above

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing ? nothing happens on the dropdown change ?

Comment: I am Getting alert if I add 4 digits and select six from dropdown. but I also want to check the vice versa. that is first  I select dropdown value is six now and if i enter 12 digits I should get alert.

Comment: This means you would get an alert everytime a user changes the input ? if you enter 6 characters you would get 5 alerts before finally having a correct result ? or you want to reverse check only if you get to 6 or 12 chars ?

Comment: I am not sure how can I achieve this, which is the correct way to check both the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

What your asking for is not very clear, but I feel like you're trying to do more than you need to.

If 'sixnumeric' just means a 6 digit number, you could do something like pull the value from the textbox, use isNaN to determine if it is a valid number, and if it passes that check validate it against the dropdown value.

Heads up, isNaN will return true on a string of spaces or an empty string so you will need to check those cases as well.

isNaN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

isNaN and empty strings: [Why does isNaN(" ") equal false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-equal-false)