# Javascript check if an string is a valid number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, string, typescript

What is the correct way to check if a string is valid number in javascript?

Normally we use `isNaN(str)`, this works great in all cases but excepts,

Current behaviour:

```
isNaN("1") = false, is a number,
isNaN("1 ") = false, But this is a string.
```

What is the correct approach to deal with this?

Expected results:

```
isNotNumber("1") = false
isNotNumber("1 ") = true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does isNaN(" ") (string with spaces) equal false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825402/why-does-isnan-string-with-spaces-equal-false)

Comment: It _should_ be false for both values. They both can be converted to a number successfully.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of an odd case. I don't know of any native JS solution for this, but you could do the following:

```
function isNotNumber(subj: string): boolean {
  const nr = +subj;
  
  return isNaN(nr) || nr.toString().length !== subj.length;
}
```

[example with tests](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-drake-5bb4g)

Answer (score -1):

I believe with Regular expressions you can achieve this easily

```js
const isNotNumber = (value) => !/^\d+$/.test(value)

console.log(isNotNumber("1")) // false
console.log(isNotNumber(" 1")) // true
```