# Is NaN equal to NaN?

Tags: javascript, function, nan, parseint, parsefloat

```
parseFloat("NaN")
```

returns "NaN", but

```
parseFloat("NaN") == "NaN"
```

returns false. Now, that's probably a good thing that it does return false, but I don't understand how this is so. Did the JavaScript creators just make this a special case? Because otherwise I can't understand how this returns false.

Comment: A NaN is never equal to itself, by definition. It works this way in any language.

Comment: Note [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12628417/1195056) as a precise method for checking this has been added with ECMAScript 6.

Comment: The event best part is that `parseFloat("A") == parseFloat("A")` return `false`

Comment: @MariuszJamro That's because `parseFloat("A")` returns `NaN` on each side. As the answers have covered, `NaN` is not even equal to itself.

Comment: `parseFloat("NaN") == NaN` <-- this is the more interesting question (without the quotes). Still no. `NaN` is toxic. Use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When a JavaScript function returns `NaN`, this is not a literal string but an object property in the global space. You cannot compare it to the string `"NaN"`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: NaN is not an object; it is a special primitive value. (Which happens to be the value of a read-only property _of_ the global object).

Answer (score 41):

***Update 2***

New to ECMAScript 6 is the [Object.is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) function. This is designed to be a further enhancement of the `===` check. One of the benefits of this new function is that `Object.is(NaN, NaN)` will now return true. If you're [able to utilize ECMAScript 6](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.is), then this would be the most readable and consistent solution for you.

**Original**

The proper way to check this would be:

```
isNaN(parseInt(variable))
```

If whatever you're checking is a NaN, that function will return true. This method is built into the JavaScript spec.

**Using jQuery**

jQuery built in their own `isNaN` function originally to help counter some discrepancies between browsers, and add some additional checks so their version can be used instead of the one in VanillaJS.

**Update for jQuery**

After jQuery 1.7, they changed this function to [`$.isNumeric()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/).

[Documentation of the switch](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10478)

If you take a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115548/why-is-isnannull-false-in-js), you'll find plenty of times where `isNaN()` returns what would intuitively be considered an "incorrect" answer, but is correct by the spec.

One of the big reasons to avoid the vanilla `isNaN()` is that `null` will return `false`, making you think it is a number. However, the jQuery function covers a much larger range of intuitive results.

From their documentation:

> As of jQuery 3.0 $.isNumeric() returns true only if the argument is of
>   type number, or if it's of type string and it can be coerced into
>   finite numbers. In all other cases, it returns false.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. What?

Comment: Just because jQuery changed the function they're using doesn't mean you have to.

Comment: `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` have the fairly significant problem of accepting "garbage" characters that appear in a string *after* a valid number.

Answer (score 37):

It's a special case, NaN is the only thing in Javascript not equal to itself.

Although the other answers about strings vs the NaN object are right too.

Comment: Why then does "NaN" == "NaN" return true? It probably wouldn't make sense for that to return false, but...

Comment: @joseph "NaN" == "NaN" is comparing two (equal) strings.

Answer (score 12):

`NaN` is one of the few examples of an object which is not equal to itself. In fact, this very property is used to implement the common `bool IsNaN(number)` method:

```
function isNaN(x)
{ 
    return x != x; 
}
```

Comment: that's funny looking *javascript*

Comment: Changed the example from C# to JavaScript.

Comment: "few examples"? is there another one? If so this implementation fails on those other examples.

Comment: `NaN` is not an object at all, it is a constant with type number.

Answer (score 9):

`isNaN` works for all values that aren't numbers

```
isNaN('foo') == true // a string is indeed not a number
isNaN(NaN) == true
isNaN(12) == false
isNaN([1,2,3]) == true // an array is also not a number
```

If, however you want to check for `NaN` specifically, or avoid type coercion;
 you can use `Number.isNaN` instead

```
Number.isNaN('foo') == false
Number.isNaN(NaN) == true
Number.isNaN(12) == false
Number.isNaN([1,2,3]) == false
```

Answer (score 8):

- When `Number` (returned by ParseFloat) compares with `string` `string` converted to `Number`
- `NaN` is not equal to any other object ( including `NaN`)

You get `NaN==NaN` . It is false by second rule.

Answer (score 1):

In  ECMAScript 6  Object.is() is an enhancement of ===.
This method accepts two arguments and returns true if the values are equivalent.And the two values are considered equivalent when they are of the same type and have the same value.
That's the reason because console.log(Object.is(NaN, NaN))--> TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Google Apps Script and so I'm stuck with ECMA 5.  Similar to Electric Coffee's answer, here's what I was able to figure out that seems to give a sure answer as to whether or not a value is actually `NaN`, not if a value is `NaN` but if it is actually `NaN` itself:

```
function isThisNaN(x)
{ 
    return isNaN(x) && Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === '[object Number]'; 
}
console.log(isThisNaN(NaN)); // true
```

lol Just funny to me that `Object.prototype.toString.call(NaN)` equals `'[object Number]'`.  My newbie brain tells me that `NaN` is "Not a Number" but sadly it's just not that simple.

EDIT: 
I guess I should have said how I ended up at this article.  I went with the idea that *surely* a string that doesn't contain a number wouldn't be treated as a number... well, I ended up finding this out:

```
isNaN('a'); // true
isNaN(' '); // false
```

so even though `' '` is a non-numerical string it apparently gets coaxed into a number (`0`).

```
console.log(Number(' ')); // 0.0
```

however...

```
console.log( 0  ? true : false); // false
console.log(' ' ? true : false); // true
```

After reading more I do understand it a bit better but wow what a mental crapstorm for a newbie lol