# In JavaScript, why is "0" equal to false, but when tested by 'if' it is not false by itself?

Tags: javascript, boolean

The following shows that `"0"` is false in Javascript:

```
>>> "0" == false
true

>>> false == "0"
true
```

So why does the following print `"ha"`?

```
>>> if ("0") console.log("ha")
ha
```

Comment: `"0"` is a string, and since it's not empty, it's evaluated to true.

Comment: `"0" === false [...] false`

Comment: Check out Angus Croll's article truth in javascript. http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: `'0'==false` but '0' is not a falsey value (yes Javascript can be weird)

Comment: @Linsey: The whole "falsy" and "truthy" thing was only ever meant to explain how values are converted to booleans. When you compare two values with `==`, they **never** get converted to booleans, so it doesn't apply. (The rules for the conversion seem to favour converting to numbers.)

Comment: `== false` and `== true` are fundamentally wrong things to do.

Comment: related: [Why does !!1==“1” equal true and !!2==“2” equal false?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23693089/1048572)

Comment: `==` is generally Considered Harmful in JavaScript; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1168116) for more.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

The reason is because when you explicitly do `"0" == false`, both sides are being converted to numbers, and *then* the comparison is performed.

When you do: `if ("0") console.log("ha")`, the string value is being tested. Any non-empty string is `true`, while an empty string is `false`.

> ***Equal (==)***
>
> If the two operands are **not of the same type**, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is **a number or a boolean**, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is **a string**, the other operand is converted to a string if possible. If **both operands are objects**, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.
>
> (From [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) in Mozilla Developer Network)

Answer (score 430):

Tables displaying the issue:

[image: truthy if statement]

and ==
[image: truthy comparisons of all object types in javascript]

Moral of the story use ===
[image: strict equality displaying sanity]

table generation credit: https://github.com/dorey/JavaScript-Equality-Table

Comment: It makes much more sense with another order of values https://gist.github.com/kirilloid/8165660

Comment: From now on, if someone says that he never uses strict comparison operators, I will face him with these tables and make him cry. Still not sure if I grasp the concept of `NaN` though. I mean, `typeof NaN  // number` but `NaN === NaN // false`, hmm...

Comment: A friend of mine made http://f.cl.ly/items/3b0q1n0o1m142P1P340P/javascript_equality.html - the same graphs as above, but a bit easier to read.

Comment: @JustusRomijn there are multiple values to represent `NaN`, so when you are comparing 2 NaNs, they are of different values (I guess). Read the first quote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18069733/278405#get-the-number-18437736874454810627).

Comment: This is really useful. And when i look at the table for ==, i once more know why i avoid that kind of comparison completely forever.

Comment: These tables have a mistake. Neither `==` nor `===` operator for the `[]`, `{}`, `[[]]`, `[0]` and `[1]` values do not evaluate to true. I mean `[] == []` and `[] === []` also false.

Comment: Herbertusz: not necessarily.  I think the chart is implying that the comparison is performed on the same object in those cases, like `var foo = []; if(foo === foo);`, etc.

Comment: unified table https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/unified/

Comment: That lower right corner is now green if you use `Object.is()`. Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12628417/1195056) about how to determine if `NaN` is equal to `NaN`.

Comment: @Taywee I like your explanation, but [that source changed the chart to match what Herbrtusz expected at some point](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/).

Answer (score 44):

It's according to spec.

```
12.5 The if Statement 
.....

2. If ToBoolean(GetValue(exprRef)) is true, then 
a. Return the result of evaluating the first Statement. 
3. Else, 
....
```

ToBoolean, according to the spec, is

> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 11:

And that table says this about strings:

[image]

> The result is  false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); 
>   otherwise the result is true

Now, to explain why `"0" == false` you should read the equality operator, which states it gets its value from the abstract operation `GetValue(lref)` matches the same for the right-side.

Which describes this relevant part as:

```
if IsPropertyReference(V), then 
a. If HasPrimitiveBase(V) is false, then let get be the [[Get]] internal method of base, otherwise let get
be the special [[Get]] internal method defined below. 
b. Return the result of calling the get internal method using base as its this value, and passing 
GetReferencedName(V) for the argument
```

Or in other words, a string has a primitive base, which calls back the internal get method and ends up looking false.

If you want to evaluate things using the GetValue operation use `==`, if you want to evaluate using the `ToBoolean`, use `===` (also known as the "strict" equality operator)

Comment: `"a string has a primitive base, which calls back the internal get method and ends up looking false"` Is this true for all strings ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder `Section 8.12.3: [[Get]] (P)` describes how it works. It's true only for cases that string are 0, as it does a bunch of other internal calls eventually resulting in `GetOwnProperty` which sees that "whatever" is a data property, which then returns all the way back that value. This is why "0" is false, and "blah" is true. Check out some of Douglas Crockford's videos on Yahoo developer theater, he describes "truthyness" in JavaScript a little less complex than I am. If you understand what "truthy" and "falsy" means you'll understand Bobince's answer right away.

Comment: Where can I find the spec?

Answer (score 13):

It's PHP where the string `"0"` is falsy (false-when-used-in-boolean-context). In JavaScript, all non-empty strings are truthy.

The trick is that `==` against a boolean doesn't evaluate in a boolean context, it converts to number, and in the case of strings that's done by parsing as decimal. So you get Number `0` instead of the truthiness boolean `true`.

This is a really poor bit of language design and it's one of the reasons we try not to use the unfortunate `==` operator. Use `===` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Your quotes around the `0` make it a string, which is evaluated as true.

Remove the quotes and it should work.

```
if (0) console.log("ha")
```

Comment: correct, not about how to "make it work" but the question is more like, "why it behaved that way?"

Comment: It's funny that after all these years the correct answer is sitting right here yet so few people notice. @JasonGennaro, thank you for not overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 8):

```
// I usually do this:

x = "0" ;

if (!!+x) console.log('I am true');
else      console.log('I am false');

// Essentially converting string to integer and then boolean.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is all because of the ECMA specs ... `"0" == false` because of the rules specified here http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3 ...And `if ('0')` evaluates to true because of the rules specified here http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.5

Comment: I didn't know someone ported the spec to a site... that's awesome! No more PDFs for me.

Answer (score 2):

**==** Equality operator evaluates the arguments after converting them to numbers.
**So string zero "0" is converted to Number data type and  boolean false is converted to Number 0.** 
So

> `"0" == false // true`

Same applies to `

> `false == "0" //true`

**===** Strict equality check evaluates the arguments with the original data type

> `"0" === false // false, because "0" is a string and false is boolean`

Same applies to

> `false === "0" // false`

In

> `if("0") console.log("ha");`

The String "0" is not comparing with any arguments, and string is a true value until or unless it is compared with any arguments.
It is exactly like

> `if(true) console.log("ha");`

But

> `if (0) console.log("ha"); // empty console line, because 0 is false`

`

Answer (score 2):

This is because JavaScript uses type coercion in Boolean contexts and your code

```
if ("0")
```

will be coerced to true in boolean contexts.

There are other truthy values in Javascript which will be coerced to true in boolean contexts, and thus execute the if block are:-

```
if (true)
if ({})
if ([])
if (42)
if ("0")
if ("false")
if (new Date())
if (-42)
if (12n)
if (3.14)
if (-3.14)
if (Infinity)
if (-Infinity)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason why you should whenever possible use strict equality `===` or strict inequality `!==`

`"100" == 100`

`true` because this only checks value, not the data type

`"100" === 100`

`false` this checks value and data type

Answer (score 1):

The "if" expression tests for truthiness, while the double-equal tests for type-independent equivalency.  A string is always truthy, as others here have pointed out.  If the double-equal were testing both of its operands for truthiness and then comparing the results, then you'd get the outcome you were intuitively assuming, i.e. `("0" == true) === true`.  As Doug Crockford says in his excellent *JavaScript: the Good Parts*, "the rules by which [== coerces the types of its operands] are complicated and unmemorable.... The lack of transitivity is alarming."  It suffices to say that one of the operands is type-coerced to match the other, and that "0" ends up being interpreted as a numeric zero, which is in turn equivalent to false when coerced to boolean (or false is equivalent to zero when coerced to a number).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x)
```

coerces x using JavaScript's internal toBoolean (http://es5.github.com/#x9.2)

```
x == false
```

coerces both sides using internal toNumber coercion (http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) or toPrimitive for objects (http://es5.github.com/#x9.1)

For full details see http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, I found a working solution as below:

The reason is

```
    if (0) means false, if (-1, or any other number than 0) means true. following value are not truthy, null, undefined, 0, ""empty string, false, NaN
```

never use number type like id as

```
      if (id) {}
```

for id type with possible value 0, we can not use if (id) {}, because  if (0) will means false, invalid, which we want it means valid as true id number.

So for id type, we must use following:

```
   if ((Id !== undefined) && (Id !== null) && (Id !== "")){
                                                                                
                                                                            } else {

                                                                            }
```

for other string type, we can use if (string) {},  because null, undefined, empty string all will evaluate at false, which is correct.

```
       if (string_type_variable) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS "==" sign does not check the type of variable. Therefore, "0" = 0 = false (in JS 0 = false) and will return true in this case, but if you use "===" the result will be false.

When you use "if", it will be "false" in the following case:

```
[0, false, '', null, undefined, NaN] // null = undefined, 0 = false
```

So

```
if("0") = if( ("0" !== 0) && ("0" !== false) && ("0" !== "") && ("0" !== null) && ("0" !== undefined) && ("0" !== NaN) )
        = if(true && true && true && true && true && true)
        = if(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here from search looking for a solution to evaluating `"0"` as a boolean.
The technicalities are explained above so I won't go into it but I found a quick type cast solves it.

So if anyone else like me is looking to evaluate a string `1` or `0` as boolean much like PHP. Then you could do some of the above or you could use `parseInt()` like:

```
x = "0";
if(parseInt(x))
//false
```