# how does if condition evaluates its value in javascript

Tags: javascript

How does javascript if condition determines its value?, see this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var bar = ("something" == true);
alert(bar); // 1

if ("something") {
    alert("hey!"); // 2
}

</script>
```

Why do I get to point //2 while 'bar' at //1 is false?

As I can see `bar` value gets calculated in almost the same way the if condition, or it doesn't?

Comment: The issue here might be the unpredictability of `==` over `===`.

Comment: Ahh the [JavaScript truth table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1998224/419956)...

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Javascript, why is "0" equal to false, but not false by itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-not-false-by-itself)

Comment: after looking that truth table... I think I will try to use `===` always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of how the javascript type coercion engine works.  When you say

```
"something" == true
```

javascript calls ToNumber on your "something" string to compare it to the boolean.  "something" produce NaN which does not equal true.

However

```
if("something")
```

only checks if the string is truthy.  Because it's not an empty string, it is in fact truthy.

More here: http://webreflection.blogspot.co.il/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

Answer (score 4):

`"something" == true` is false because the string and the boolean have to be coerced into types that can be compared. However, `if("something")` works because a non-empty string is a truthy value.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in the first case, JavaScript will attempt to compare them as strings (lit. `"something" == "true"`), which will be false.

However, in the second condition, the result of the expression is `"something"`, which when cast to a Boolean, is `true`.

**[See here for details.](https://twitter.com/mattmight/status/191964430312030208)**

Comment: But `"true" == true` evaluates to `false` too. If its just comparing as Strings(like you have indicated), this should have been `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if("something")
```

The declaration above will return `true` because `"something"` is a valid string. It would return `false` if it was an empty string (`""`). It also happens with number (`0` returns `false`, but `1` returns `true`).

In `"something"==true`, both are converted to strings and then checked ("something"=="true", which will return `false`).

Answer (score 0):

The thing is not so much how javascript handles if statements as it is how javascript coerces object types.

A non empty string is truthy, although it does not equal true. You can check this if you trye `"something != false` which returns `true`.

Because of this a lot of people advocate the strict comparison in JavaScript to avoid these pitfalls.

For example:

```
"something" !== false // true
"something" === true  // false
"" === false          // false
0 === false           // false
```

To read up on this, there are a ton of articles. I'd recommend [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html).

Comment: Now I'm confused, both `"something" == false` and `"something" == true` are false, why?

Comment: Because when `==` tries to do its type coercion thing, `true`, `false`, and `'something'` always come out to be the different values.  Not really surprising in that case, considering `'something'` isn't a boolean anyway (so comparing them doesn't make sense).

Comment: Read again, it says `("something" != false)` and `("something" == false)`