# Javascript Functions and default parameters, not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function like this:

```
function saveItem(andClose = false) {

}
```

It works fine in Firefox

In IE it gives this error on the console:
`Expected ')'`

In Chrome it gives this error in the console:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Both browsers mark the source of the error as the function creation line.

Comment: Android stock browser 5.1.1 here, same issue.

Answer (score 165):

You can't do this, but you can instead do something like:

```
function saveItem(andClose) {
   if(andClose === undefined) {
      andClose = false;
   }
}
```

This is often shortened to something like:

```
function setName(name) {
  name = name || 'Bob';
}
```

***Update***

The above is true for ECMAScript <= 5. ES6 has proposed [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters). So the above could instead read:

```
function setName(name = 'Bob') {}
```

Comment: This is useful for IE11 and under, which doesn't implement ES6 and breaks on default parameters.

Comment: Thanks!! Didn't know that! IE sucks but developers don't have a choice other than to support a "non"-browser.

Comment: `name = name || 'Bob';` shouldn't be used because if name is set to a falsey value, the default will be used instead of name

Comment: Instead of ```name = name || 'Bob'``` use 
```name = (name === undefined) ? '' : name;```

Comment: @juco I don't understand "You can't do this" - Mozilla MDN says we can? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters  Are you just saying that you can't do it in IE or are you saying the Mozilla docs are inaccurate?

Comment: @php-b-grader The docs say you can't use this in IE

Answer (score 14):

That's not a valid ECMAScript syntax, but it is a valid syntax for Mozilla's superset of features they add to their implementation of the language.

Default parameter assignment syntax is *likely* coming in ECMAScript 6.

Comment: Ok, so what is the best way to set default values in Javascript functions?

Comment: @Talon: The best way depends on your situation. If you know the argument won't be falsey, you can do `foo = foo || "the default"`. Or you can check the `.length` of the `arguments` object. Or you can simply test each parameter for `undefined`. There are different occasions to use each.

Answer (score 9):

Javascript does not allow a "default" specifier.

A quick way of doing what you would want is changing:

```
function saveItem(andClose = false) {

}
```

to the following:

```
function saveItem(andClose) {
    // this line will check if the argument is undefined, null, or false
    // if so set it to false, otherwise set it to it's original value
    var andClose = andClose || false;

    // now you can safely use andClose
    if (andClose) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: it will set `andClose` to false it was 0... not quite what I would expect it to do...

Comment: @gdoron see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-not-false-by-itself these are the quirks you need to learn about any language you use.

Comment: an alternative is to change the third line to `var andClose = andClose === undefined? false: andClose;` That will enable you to pass `0` to the function and not have it replaced with `false`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided won't run in Chrome < version 49:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-default_function_parameters

You used valid ECMAScript 2015 syntax:

- [MDN: Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).
- [ES2015 Spec: default value parameter initializers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation)

In my opinion, the best way to use ES2015 features is to bundle assets with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [WebPack](https://webpack.github.io/), with a step for using [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to trans-compile ES2015 to ES5. That way you don't have to worry about that ES2015 browser compatibility chart. It's a pain to get started the first time, but worth it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have an other alternative to be sure that your variable is a boolean:

```
function saveItem(andClose) {
  andClose = true == andClose;
  // ...
}
```

Default value is `undefined`, and `true == undefined` => `false`, so your default value will be `false` :)

Comment: One minor adjustment would be to remove the var declaration as the `andClose` variable is already assigned in this scope

Comment: If you really want to be sure it's a boolean and not the string 'true', change it to `andClose = true === andClose;`