# unable to understand working of this function

Tags: jquery

To check weather the element is exist or not I am using

```
   if($('#id').length)
       //statement 1
   else
      //statement 2
```

It is working fine for me. But statement1 will execute when the condition is true otherwise statement2 will execute. But how is it working when length is returning length (it is a number like 1 , 2...)

I thought if the length is 0, then it is taking `false` for `0`. But what about remaining cases. I am unable to understand what is happening here. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think $('#id').length returns a string. Try praseInt() on the result....

Comment: @JayBhatt No, it returns a number.

Comment: why downvote .Please leave a comment before giving a downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the MDN on if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) :

> Any value that is not
>   undefined, null, 0, NaN, or the empty string (""), and any object,
>   including a Boolean object whose value is false, evaluates to true
>   when passed to a conditional statement

This means that when the length is `1` (or greater but that can't happen for this selector) then it evaluates to true.

So when the element with id `id` is found, the `statement 1` is executed. when the length is `0`, then `statement 2` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some output from the chrome console, that might help you:

```
> Boolean(1) //The number 1
true

> Boolean(0) //The number 0
false

> Boolean(0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001) //A very close to 0 float
true

> Boolean(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001) //This is where it starts rounding down to zero
false

> Boolean(false) //A boolean "false"
false

> Boolean(NaN) //Not a number
false

> Boolean(undefined) //Undefined
false

> Boolean("") //An empty string
false

> Boolean(-3) //A negative number
true

> Boolean("string") //A string that is not empty
true

> Boolean([]) //An empty array
true

> Boolean({}) //An empty object
true

> Boolean(2.5) //A float
true
```

..hence, if length is 0 (as in; the element could not be found) then it does not evaluate to `true` and therefore chooses the `} else {` statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a concept of [truthy/falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) where values like `0`, false, `undefined` and `null` are considered to be falsy and others are considered to be truthy.

If if the length is `0` then it becomes falsy and the condition will fail, else if length !=0 then the value is considered to be truthy and the condition will succeed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is how javascript works

An explanation here

[In JavaScript, why is "0" equal to false, but when tested by 'if' it is not false by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-not-false-by-itself)