# Are these comparisons equivalent in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is

```
return (someBooleanValue == true)
```

necessarily always the same as

```
return someBooleanValue
```

?

Comment: No, try e.g. `[1]` or [any of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22==+true%22+javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-not-false-by-itself

Comment: What is `someBooleanValue`?  Are we assuming it *is* a boolean value?  Can it ever be anything else?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, I was trying to convey that it is always a Boolean value by the way I named it but I guess I should have explicitly mentioned that.

Comment: @BVernon: I just wanted to make sure, even though it looked obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iff `someBooleanValue` is a boolean value, then yes.  For any other object/value, then no.

Comment: Well, there are many objects that would behave like Boolean objects?

Comment: Why does this have a downvote?  The OP said (in a comment) that he is working with a boolean, hence `someBooleanValue`.

Comment: The question was: "necessarily always the same as".  Abstract other types which behave like Boolean objects seems out of scope to me.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Not my downvote (I'm still considering it), but this answer talks about `Boolean` *objects*, not *boolean values*.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that `typeof someBooleanValue` is `'boolean'`, then **Yes** these are equivalent (by pure boolean logic).

For everything else, they are not.