# If statement with only a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

I found this function to put numbers in fractions and I am trying to figure out what everything means. There is one thing I can't figure out.

Here's the code:

```
function reduce(numerator,denominator) {
  var gcd = function gcd (a,b) {
    if (b) {
      return gcd(b, a%b);
    } else {
      return a;
    }
  };
  gcd = gcd(numerator,denominator);
  return [numerator/gcd, denominator/gcd];
}
```

What does the `if (b)` mean. I know that if there is just the variable in the if statement it is checking if the variable is true or false. How would this apply to a number? When would this go to the else statement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-not-false-by-itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is to do with how things get converted to *Boolean*, i.e. whether something is *truthy* or not

```js
if (0 || NaN || undefined) {                // these are "falsy"
    // this never happens
} else if (1 /* or any other number*/ ){    // these are "truthy"
    // this happens
}
```

Comment: May be more concise to write `x != 0` is truthy (either negative or positive)

Comment: @BradChristie `NaN != 0; // true`

Answer (score 3):

If `b` is:

- `0`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`
- Or an empty string `""`

it will be evaluated as false. Otherwise, it will be evaluated as true.

Comment: don't forget `NaN` :D

Comment: Added NaN. I thought of adding false too, but... :)

Answer (score 0):

Any expression in `if` statement will be implicitly converted to `boolean` before evaluated.

In the code you posted, it's usually used to check if a parameter is passed, in which case `undefined` is a falsy value and will be converted to `false`. AJPerez has given an answer on the falsy values (except for he forgot `NaN`).

```
function reduce(numerator,denominator){
    var gcd = function gcd(a,b){
    if (b) {
        // if two arguments are passed, do something
        return gcd(b, a%b);
    }  
    else {
        // only one argument passed, return it directly
        return a;
    }
  };
    gcd = gcd(numerator,denominator);
    return [numerator/gcd, denominator/gcd];
}
```

However, this approach may be buggy if the argument you're checking is indeed passed by falsy.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can check if the variable is assigned by putting it in an if statement. If it has a value it will be true (well unless its value is false or 0). If it has no value or evaluates at null it will return false. Looks like they are verifying it has a value before passing it into the function.