# How does JS type coercion work?

Tags: javascript, equality, coercion

I'm learning about `==` vs. `===` and came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523650/863846) which was very helpful in understanding the concept. However I wondered about one of the examples:

```
'0' == false     // true
```

This might make sense, since `==` doesn't check for type. But then I tried some possible coercions in the console and found the following:

```
Boolean('0')     // true
String(false)    // "false"
```

I would have thought `'0' == false` has the same truth value as `'0' === String(false)`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So how does the coercion actually work? Is there a more basic type I'm missing?

Comment: String(false) is returning the String representation of false, whilst Boolean('0') is converting the string '0' into true (as a non empty string is truthy)

Comment: Answers to all your questions you can find here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/ A little hard to read at first but you will benefit a lot, if you spend some time reading through.

Comment: Some [possibly surprising examples of `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47015438/199364).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"0"` is a string containing the character *0*, it is **not** the numeric value `0`. The only string-type value which evaluates to `false` is `""`.

`"0"` is [*truthy*](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/).

[Section 9.2 of the ECMAScript 262 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) defines how different types are converted to Boolean:

```
Argument Type   Result
Undefined       false
Null            false
Boolean         The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
Number          The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the
                result is true.
String          The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is
                zero); otherwise the result is true.
Object          true
```

This, however, is only strictly followed when comparing using `===`.

When using `Boolean('0')` you're converting the value `'0'` to Boolean (which is the same as using `!!'0'`). When loosely comparing `'0'` with `false`, the Boolean value is converted to a number (as defined [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)). `false`, when converted to a number, becomes `0`. This means the final calculation is `'0' == 0` which equates to `true`.

To summarise the relevant part of the linked section of the ECMAScript specification above:

1. Let *x* = `'0'` and *y* = `false`.
2. Check if the type of *y* is Boolean.
3. If true, convert *y* to a number.
4. Compare *x* to the numeric equivalent of *y*.

In our case, a JavaScript implementation of this would be:

```
var x = '0',                      // x = "0"
    y = false;                    // y = false

if (typeof y === "boolean") {
    y = +y;                       // y = 0
}

console.log( x == y );            // "0" == 0
```

```
-> true
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. If "0" is truthy, how can `'0' == false` be true?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-not-false-by-itself

Comment: Thanks @james-donnelly! That link was exactly what I was looking for, but didn't know it :)

Comment: @LucyBain I've added a little update to my answer which will hopefully make everything clear. The key part of the ECMAScript specification is http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3, specifically points 6 and 7.

Comment: @LucyBain slow day at work, so I've also added a JavaScript method of how to apply the ECMAScript's definition of how to compare using `==`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that update made it really clear! And the specification was really helpful - I thought it took the type from the first operand. TIL :)

Answer (score 0):

To make things more confusing for totally new in programming world:

```
Boolean('false')
true

Boolean('true')
true
```

I think it is easier and more intuitive to use `!!` operator for some reason. I dont know if i make sense, but i never used `Boolean()`

Answering the question, i found that thread useful: [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: that SO question is where I got my example from, but I couldn't figure out how it worked. I'll stick with `===` for now :)