# Why is "0" == [] false?

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log( 0 == '0' );     // true
console.log( 0 == [] );     // true 
console.log( [] == '0' );    // false
```

Why does JavaScript evaluate the expression like this?

Comment: The number `0` is falsey, the string `"0"` is not.

Comment: Because true ('0') is not false ([])

Comment: @Jamiec But if "0" isn't falsey, why is `"0" == false` => `true`?

Comment: `Boolean([])` returns `true` , not `false`

Comment: @Jamiec is right. But Javascript will also try to convert one type to another in the case of == (that's why it's recommended to use ===)

While it's not possible to convert a string to an array, it's surely possible to convert a string to an int. Thus, you still get true.

Yes, Javascript does a lot of magic during simple equal comparison.

Comment: @Philicare That's genius. But why `'0'` is `true` and `[]` is `false`?

Comment: Sorry, flippant comment - fuller answer below.

Comment: For the same reason that `[] == false` and `![] == false`.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: but,console.log([]); not return false

Comment: see http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ ; tl;dr: JS `==` is not transitive (it's symmetric though); as such, `a == b` && `b == c` does not imply `a == c`

Comment: 1. Ask a question about javascript conversions on SO 2. Profit

Comment: In my opinion this is the most correct answer:

1. Convert `[]` to primitive type: `[].toString() === ''`, `toString` is calling by [ToPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)
2. now `[]` is `''` (empty string) '' == '0' // false

When instead of `'0'` is `0`, then `''` (array) is also coverting to number `0`, thats why 
`0 == []` is `true`.

Just read [this](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

JavaScript will try to coerce types when using double equals operator (`==`). Exact details in spec: [sec 11.9.3: Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

**Example 1:**

```
console.log( 0 == '0' );     // true
```

JavaScript coerces the string to the number `0`, so `0 == 0`.

**Example 2:**

```
console.log( 0 == [] ); // true
```

An empty array's "ToPrimitive" value is zero, when comparing to a number. So this one reduces to `0 == 0`.

**Example 3:**

```
 console.log( [] == '0' ); // false
 console.log( [] == '' ); // true
```

While the first one looks quite similar to the previous example, neither side is a number. At first glance this appears to be a `truthy` comparison, BUT `[]` is *not* one of the eight [`falsy` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).
Demonstrating that `[]` is truthy, but `''` is falsy:

```
 console.log( [] ? true : false ); // true
 console.log( '' ? true : false ); // false
```

In any sane language, the above two statements would imply that `[] == ''` would be `false`. But as we saw earlier, that isn't the case in JavaScript!

INEXPLICABLY, `[]` converts to `false` when using `==`:

```
 console.log( [] == true ); // false
 console.log( [] == false ); // true
```

Conclusion: both sides are converted to booleans, but NOT by the "normal" "truthy/falsy" rule (which would convert `[]` to `true`, because it is not one of the eight falsy values). Instead, `[]` converts to `false` when using `==`:

```
 console.log( [] == '0' ); // `false == true`, so false
 console.log( [] == '' ); // `false == false`, so true
```

**Example 4:**

```
 console.log( [0] == '' ); // false
 console.log( [1] == '' ); // false
```

This could *EITHER* indicate that the *length* of the array (`1`), which is "truthy", is compared to `''`, which is "falsy", so `true == false`, which is `false`. *OR* it could indicate that no type conversion is appropriate, which is case (10) in the spec, so `false`. BUT see example 5, which doesn't seem to fit either possibility.

**Example 5:**

```
 console.log( [0] == '0' ); // true
 console.log( [0] == '1' ); // false
 console.log( [1] == '1' ); // true
 console.log( [1] == '0' ); // false
 console.log( [2] == '2' ); // true
 console.log( [1] == '2' ); // false
```

Surprisingly, an array that contains one number, apparently is converted to that number, when comparing to a *non-empty string*. This then goes to the rule for comparing a number to string, which converts the string to a number. So we are comparing either (`0` or `1` or ..) to (`0` or `1` or ..).
Is this an ambiguity in the spec? Differs between different implementations?
Testing done at `https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html` on 2020-Oct-27, in Chrome on a Windows 10 pc, using `alert` instead of `console.log`.

**Example 6:**

If all the above doesn't convince you to never use `==` again, consider this:

```
var a = [];
console.log( a == a ); // true
```

BUT:

```
console.log( [] == [] ); // false
```

None of the 9 type conversion rules in the spec apply, so this is case 10: they aren't the same object, even though neither of them has any contents. They are two different instances of an empty array.

---

In all, this is why its generally safer to use triple equals, which checks type and equality.

A handy illustration (for the cases that test truthiness) below:

```js
function truthyOrFalsy(val) {
    return val ? "Truthy" : "Falsy";
}

console.log("empty array:", truthyOrFalsy([]));
console.log("number zero:", truthyOrFalsy(0));
console.log("string with a zero character:", truthyOrFalsy("0"));
```

Comment: Where can read about this? About how this conversion is happening?

Comment: @TheChetan [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) on MDN is a good place to start. There are a massive amount of questions on stackoverflow on this confusiong subject too.

Comment: @TheChetan: My advice is not to learn about it, and instead to follow Douglas Crockford's advice always use `===` to avoid having to deal with this frequently eccentric behaviour.

Comment: -1 "both sides are falsey ... one is falsey the other is not" Nope, all lists in JavaScript are truthy, even the empty list. Falsiness really doesn't have much to do with it.

Comment: @ArthurTacca Yep, the wording is probably misleading there. Can you word it better? Feel free to update the answer if you wish (more helpful to future visitors than just pointing out its wrong)

Comment: All three examples are slightly to very misleading: 1) both operands are converted to numbers, as you can see with `16 == "0x10"` or `NaN != "NaN"`. 2) Truthy/falsy has nothing to do with it; in fact `[]` *is* truthy. Both are again converted to numbers, which you can again see with `16 == ["0x10"]`. 3) Again truthy/falsy has nothing to do with it. Both are converted to strings, as you can see with `[1,2] == '1,2'`; the empty array is converted to the empty string, which is not equal to the string containing one `0`.

Comment: Ive made some updates here, hopefully iron out some of those issues.

Comment: The first two examples are much better now IMHO. The third still needs a bit of work: JavaScript in fact *can* convert them to the same type, namely strings.

Comment: "In all, this is why its generally safer to use triple equals, which checks type and equality."
This is not accurate.
source: YDKJS

Comment: Submitting an edit for code snippet #3's explanation, and a spec link. As @ETHproductions points out, this isn't quite due to truthiness; adding a 4th code snippet to demonstrate that.

Comment: More detail about @localhoost's comment. *type and equality* is accurate description for comparing *"primitive"* values (except for `NaN===NaN` which is `false`), and for strings, **but not for** other non-primitives (which are only `===` when the same object, not merely the same contents). Spec: [11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6).

Comment: MDN provided a bit more detail as to why `[] == false` is TRUE - 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean



The reason for [] == false even though [] is truthy is: the comparison [] == false compares the value of [] to false. And to get the value of [], the JavaScript engine first calls [].toString(). That results in "", and that is what’s actually compared to false. In other words, [] == false is equivalent to "" == false. And "" is falsy — and so that’s what explains the behavior in the example.

Answer (score 7):

```
/*
If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String,
return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
*/
console.log( 0 == '0');

/*
If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object,
return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
*/
console.log( 0 == [] );

/*
If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
*/
console.log( [] == '0');
```

source: http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3

Answer (score 5):

Truthy and Falsy
As well as a type, each value also has an inherent boolean value, generally known as either truthy or falsy. Some of the rules are a little bizarre so understanding the concepts and effect on comparison helps when debugging JavaScript applications.

The following values are always falsy:

- false
- 0 (zero)
- '' or "" (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (e.g. the result of 1/0)

Everything else is truthy. That includes:

- '0' (a string containing a single zero)
- 'false' (a string containing the text “false”)
- [] (an empty array)
- {} (an empty object)
- function(){} (an “empty” function)

Unexpected situations can occur when comparing truthy and falsy values using the == loose equality:

See the Loose Equality Comparison Table

[image: Table for loose equality comparison with ==]

Comment: in JS:  [] != [] and {} != {}

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses type Type Conversion to coerce any value to a Boolean in contexts that require it, such as conditionals and loops.

In first case

```
console.log( 0 == '0');
```

javascript uses coerceing and converts both to number and compares . Now 0==0 so true is returned .

In second case

```
console.log( 0 == [] );
```

**Both are falsy** (A falsy value is a value that translates to false when evaluated in a Boolean context ) . So now comparing false == false , true value is returned .

In 3rd case

```
console.log( [] == '0');
```

[] is falsy and '0' is string , js is not able to coerce them to convert the to type which can be compared . so false is returned .

Comment: "such as conditionals and loops" — This is neither a conditional nor a loop. It is an equals operator. The first case will convert `'0'` to a number not a string. The second case will convert the array to a number. The third case will convert the array to to a string and compare them. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: That document says it applies in a Boolean context. == is not a Boolean context.