# Why ![] and [] == false yelds different results?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between those two? I would expect it be equal

`![]` yields `false`

`[] == false` yields `true`

`![] != []==false` yields `true` while I would expect it to be `false`. Why is that? If `[]` is falsy, shouldn't both expression evaluate to `true` ??

Comment: falsy means that when evaluated as `if (something)` it's not going to trigger the body of the statement. It doesn't mean it's *false*.

Comment: @VLAZ therfore i am using `==` not `===`

Comment: I can't do anything but repeat the same - falsy is not false. Loose equality comparison doesn't change that.

Comment: I guess i dont understand how it works as i thought that == allow me to compare nonboolean falsy value with falsy boolean. falsy is not false, sure, therefore === will fail, but == will yeld true. Example shows that indeed I can do this as falsy [] double equals false - but why ![] does not?

Comment: That's...not what it does. `0 == "0"` will be `true` because the string will be converted to a number, for the comparison, for example, `[1, 2, 3] == 3` will also be `true` because the array will be converted to a number.

Comment: Yes, conversion happens - thats what I do understand. What I dont understand why this is different from `![]`. So why different conversion is happening when using `!x` and `x==false` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "0" == \[\] false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015361/why-is-0-false)

Comment: [Empty arrays seem to equal true and false at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5491605)

Comment: Answer there states that `if(!x)` does not actually do the conversion to boolean. If this is true, that would explain things a little bit (i think)

Comment: `if(!x)` does convert to a boolean.  Or rather `!x` does.

Comment: !x does, but X must be converted to boolean first to negate , right? so is that happening or not? If so, then the same happens [] == false here -> [] is converted somehow to boolean right ? Then we are at the begining. Why is this different ;)

So if both scenarios involves the same conversions, it should equal - but it does not. Therfore different conversion is happening (or opeartion). The question is - what sort of conversion/opration.

Comment: With `[] == false` the array is *not* converted to a boolean. [See the abstract equality algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using_). Since one operand is an object, the other a boolean, this will convert the boolean to a number (`false` -> `0`) and the other operand to a primitive. For arrays, `ToPrimitive(arr)` is the same as `arr.length` (`[]` -> `0`).

Comment: Ahh, now that expalins a thing and pinpoit exact difference between those two (i tink) which was my question abaout. Ill read about equality algorithm. Thanks Vlaz. I would accept, but thats a comment....

Comment: The MDN reference for the equality operator (`==`) might be useful reading too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality