# Why '0' == false evals true, but if I use '0' on an if statement evals true ? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
'0'== false
true
```

But if I try using '0' on a if statement, it evals true:

```
if('0') console.log(true)
true
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523765/how-does-js-type-coercion-work) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript/523650#523650) answer for some explanation of javascript coercion.

Comment: because == coerces it to false and '0' is a non-empty string, e.g truthy

Comment: mplungian, i think you mean 'ie', not 'eg' ("in other words" vs "for example")

Comment: Always mix them. Thanks