# Why is JavaScript allows it to do mathematical operations with a string type number?

Tags: javascript, string, math, numbers

```js
const num1 = 10;
const num2 = "10";

console.log(num1 * num2); // Output: 100
console.log(num2 * num2); // Output: 100
```

Comment: JavaScript performs automatic type conversion. You can view this as a convenience or a curse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has a feature called [type coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523765/how-does-js-type-coercion-work) that allows values of one type to be *implicitly* converted into a type that is acceptable for an operation.

In `"10" * 10`, JS knows that multiplication with a string and number does not make sense, so it automatically converts the string into a number.

(However, in `"10" + 10`, JS sees `+` as a string concatenation operation and produces `"1010"`.)