# Scroll Javascript functions for different parent divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll

I have a simple javascript scroll function that fixes my sidebar navigation and works fine on it's own, but I need to adjust it so different page types have different scroll events.  Example: pages with banners need to have the fixed sidebar at a different scroll point that pages without a sidebar.

The indicator of a different page will be that the sidebar for a page without a banner will have a parent div that a page with a banner will not have.  I am using a wordpress theme so my customization on this is limited.

Below is my example HTML and JS, but you can also see it at : http://jsfiddle.net/61L4ac2j/

HTML:

```
<div id="mk-page-id-1" class="theme-page-wrapper mk-main-wrapper">
<aside id="mk-sidebar" class="mk-builtin test">
<div class="sidebar-wrapper" style="min-height:600px;">
    Page without banner example
</div>
</aside>        
</div>

<div id="mk-page-id-2" class="theme-page-wrapper">
</div>
<div class="theme-page-wrapper">
<aside id="mk-sidebar" class="mk-builtin">
<div class="sidebar-wrapper" style="min-height:600px;">
    Page with banner example
</div>
</aside>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
var div = $(".sidebar-wrapper");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (($("sidebar-wrapper").parent().parent("mk-main-wrapper")) & (scroll > 147)) {
        div.css( "background", "yellow" );
    } else if (scroll > 263) {
        div.css( "background", "green" );
    } else {
        div.css( "background", "blue" );
    }
});
});
```

For simplification purposes, I used background color, but my actual JS will use "addclass".  See JS below:

```
$(function() {
var div = $(".sidebar-wrapper");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if ($("sidebar-wrapper").parent().parent("mk-main-wrapper") & scroll > 147) {
        div.addClass("fixed-product-nav");
    } else if (scroll > 263) {
        div.addClass("fixed-product-nav");
    } else {
        div.removeClass("fixed-product-nav");
    }
});
});
```

The issue is I cannot get the first IF Statement true, which you can see at the JSFiddle.  It looks like something with the parent elements.

I feel like I'm close and just missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery objects will always be truthy. You need to check the length to see if it is greater than zero.

You also do not have a class selector, it is missing the `.`

Also `&` is not correct, it needs to be `&&`

```
$("sidebar-wrapper").parent().parent("mk-main-wrapper")  & scroll > 147
```

to

```
$(".sidebar-wrapper").closest(".mk-main-wrapper").length  && scroll > 147
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but bare with me as I'm new to JS.  What do you mean check the length to see if it is greater than zero?

Comment: `....length > 0`, but you can get away with a truthy check, hence why I dropped that and just left it at length. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-not-false-by-itself

Comment: I replaced with `if ($("sidebar-wrapper").closest(".mk-main-wrapper").length  && scroll > 147) {` but it still responds the same where the first IF statement does not work.  Am i still missing something? Thank you!

Comment: Ah, your selector is wrong, missed that. You are using "element" selectors, not class "selectors". You need a "." to select a class.

Comment: I used `if ($(".sidebar-wrapper").parents(".mk-main-wrapper") && scroll > 147)` and the first IF is now true, but the second IF does not seem to work yet.  It might be weird since I'm using the same css action, but I applied to me actual page and the first IF still applied for the page that needed the second if (scroll > 263).

Comment: `$(".sidebar-wrapper").closest(".mk-main-wrapper").length  && scroll > 147` worked perfectly on my actual page.  Thanks a ton! Been playing with this for days.