# Truthy and Falsy values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here][1][testing truthy value to false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7PLi.png)

What am i missing here..

how can a truthy value campared to false yields true ?
something wrong in the code or is that a bug?
Can someone please explain that ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: which `truthy value` is being  `campared to false` in that pretty image that you should post as code here?

Comment: `spaces == false` is not what you use to determine falsiness. `!!spaces`/`Boolean(spaces)` is.

Comment: I dont know why everybody only emptyString variable. removing it from code. uploading new image.

Comment: @JatinJohny No, don't upload a new image. Add it as code/text. See the post linked by CBroe in the first comment.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here, i dont know how to post code snippet from chrome's console here. That's why posted screenshot

Comment: @Bergi,  This may not be the correct way. But why spaces == false returns true ?

Comment: See [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) You can add `console.log()`'s to your snippet to run/log the expressions. But that being said, I think the questions linked in the blue box above your question should already provide the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @JatinJohny Specifically see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33705786/479156).

Answer (score -1):

Because you use lose comparison `==` instead of strict comparison `===`, so your `emptyString` is converted to boolean to be comparable against `false`