# how does this if statement works and means? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, properties

This function counts number of all characters of a string into a string.  I am not fully understanding the if statement here and how it works.

```
function getFrequency(string) {
    var freq = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string[i];
        if (freq[character]) {
           freq[character]++;
        } else {
           freq[character] = 1;
        }
    }

    return freq;
};
```

I thought `freq[character]` is the property of the object such as `A` `B` how does it work with `if(freq[character])` also how does the increment of `freq[character]++` works?

I have made test like this to try and understand it.

```
var v = {};
v.h = 3;
v["h"]++;
v["h"] = v["h"] + 1;
v.h++;
v.h = v.h + 2;
console.log(v);
console.log(v["h"]);
```

I think I can guess the if statement works that if the property exists but I thought JS has an object property calls `.hasOwnProperty` shouldn't this be used instead?
As for the increments, to my test, it works but I just don't get the reason.

Can someone give me a hand to elaborate this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like it's counting occurrences of characters `string = 'abbcccdd'` == `freq = [1,2,3,2]`

Comment: This counts the number of occurrences of each character (letter, number, etc) in a string.  The if statement says essentially "if the [character] value of the freq object is set and has a value, then add one to it (that's what `++` does), otherwise set it to 1"

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript! [Have fun](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-when-tested-by-if-it-is-not-fals)

Comment: What exactly are you not understanding about the increment? `foo++` is imply a shorthand for `foo = Number(foo) + 1`.

Comment: @FelixKling maybe I am just not thinking straight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, objects *are* associative arrays. And vice versa. There is no difference between the two concepts.

So defining this variable as an empty object:

```
var freq = {};
```

... is actually creating an associative array (like a dictionary or map) with no keys added yet.

Moving on, let's take an input string like `eek`. The code here will look at the first letter and treat `freq[character]` the same as `freq['e']`, which is the same as `freq.e`.

In this code, the initial value of any letter in the `freq` object is **`undefined`**. So that initial `if()` check for the first "e" in our string actually looks like  this:

`if(undefined)`

Javascript has the concept of "truthy" and "falsy" values; [*anything* in javascript can be evaluated as a boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), and (in most cases) a sensible result is achieved. Looking at `undefined`, Javascript will simply treat this a falsy value, fall to the `else` block, and therefore execute this code:

```
freq[character] = 1;
```

As already established, this is the same thing as `freq.e = 1;`

Now when the loop continues to the next letter (also an "e"), javascript will end up evaluating the expression `if (1)`. Javascript treats this *and all other non-zero numbers* as "truthy", so this time will execute the following line:

```
freq[character]++;
```

Again, that's the same as `freq.e++`, where `freq.e` had a value of "1" that can now be incremented to "2".

One more time through the loop for the final letter "k". This time we get `freq.k`, which is still undefined. Undefined is falsy, so control falls to the `else` block, and `freq.k` is set to "1".

Now you can see how we can start to increment letters in the array as you find them in the string, even though it appears that you never defined an array in the first place, never set any values to anything other than "undefined", and never had a real boolean value to check against.

Comment: Wow thanks for the details, but this just got my curiosity about the `.hasOwnProperty` why do we still need this when if we can check it just like `if(object[property])` instead of using `if(object.hasOwnProperty['prop'])`

Comment: `.hasOwnProperty()` just returns a boolean. You _could_ use it, but it's more verbose.

Comment: This is off the topic, but wondering if this can be done without using objects and just returning like a list? Pretty much the same thing but not an object.

Comment: You'd need a dictionary or map, to **associate** specific letters with the count for that letter. Javascript does this via associative arrays, which again are they exact same thing as objects. In javascript, associative arrays and objects are just different ways to express in code the same underlying structure in memory.

Comment: Thanks you :D Guess I need more exercises which I am doing now :D

Answer (score 3):

`if (freq[character])` checks if the value is "truthy". That is, it's not `false`, `null`, `undefined` or `0`. The first time we encounter any character the value will be `undefined`, since the object literal is created empty, so the "truthy" check will fail and control will fall to the `else` block.

So when we first see a specific letter set the value to 1 (which is now "truthy").

Any subsequent encounters of that letter just increment the value, which would be equivalent to say `freq[character] = freq[character] + 1;`. The increment syntax is just a shorthand.

Comment: So pretty much if the property is a number value the increment will just work like that because that's how JS is? :D

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edits. Feel free to rollback if you feel they went too far.

Answer (score 2):

`if (freq[character])` checks if the object `freq` has a property on it with the value of `character` as the name.  The result of this expression evaluates to `true` or `false`.

It can be more explicitly stated, as the following non-exhaustively illustrates:

```
if (freq[character] == null)
```

or

```
if (typeof freq[character] === 'undefined')
```

The **danger** in not being explicit when evaluating if an object is `undefined` or `null`, is if it is actually set to a different type that evaluates to true or false (`0`, `1`, `'0'`, `true`, `false`).

Comment: `freq.character` is equivalent to `freq["character"]`. Property names after `.` are literals, not variables.