# Angular 2 - Local Variable/Template Reference Variable with *ngIf - ONLY first element of array not binding

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/te67zdtkVkNCUzEtW5XO?p=preview
see app.ts

**Background:**

The parent component has an array and displays one element in the array. The ChildComponent is a list displaying the array, with a variable `selectedIdx` that is set when the element is clicked.

```
selectNumber(idx: number) {
    this.selectedIdx = idx;
  }
```

The ParentComponent gets the `selectedIdx` value from the child by storing the child as a local variable `#child` and accessing it using `child.selectedIdx`.

**Problem:**

The binding between `selectedIdx` in the child component and the parent component accessing it works perfectly for every element in the array apart from the first one (index 0) - if you click `1`, the element at index 0, the `Selected Number In Parent: _` disappears.

This means the `*ngIf` is false which means `selectedIdx` is `null`.

However, this is not the case as when I set a breakpoint in the `selectNumber()` function in the child component, `this.selectedIdx` is set to 0. There must be something wacky going on with the parent retrieving the value of 0 and then thinking it's null?

Any help appreciated, thank you very much.

Based on: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-local-var

Comment: Can you share a reduced and minimal code sample of the problem?

Comment: Hi shusson, I've made the array a simple array of numbers if that simplifies the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/te67zdtkVkNCUzEtW5XO?p=preview

Comment: It looks like you got some good answers, but what I originally meant was actually show the minimal template and component in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in `Javascript` 0 == `false`, so your `*ngIf` expression returns `false` when being compared with 0.

Change it to:

```
*ngIf="child.selectedIdx !== undefined"
```

[**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-when-tested-by-if-it-is-not-fals#answer-7615326) has an excellent table about this.

Comment: Thank you! It fixed the problem. Today I learned something new about Javascript.