# String coercion into boolean

Tags: javascript, coercion

```
Boolean("a")
```

returns true in the Browser console.
So why

```
"a" == true
```

returns false?

Comment: because per the spec, any non-zero value given to the Boolean constructor is considered truthy, but for equality comparison "a' is definitely not the same value as true

Comment: I find it is illogical but I'll deal with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, why is "0" equal to false, but when tested by 'if' it is not false by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-when-tested-by-if-it-is-not-fals)

Comment: @str `"true" == true` returns `false`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the `==` operator functions on certain types is defined in the [ECMAScript specifications](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison). It is as followed:

> **7.2.13 Abstract Equality Comparison**
>
> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>      Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
> 2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ! ToNumber(y).
> 5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ! ToNumber(x) == y.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ! ToNumber(x) == y.
> 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ! ToNumber(y).
> 8. If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
> 9. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
> 10. Return false.

Now we can apply them to this the cases above. Which first converts the boolean into a number and then attempts to convert the string into a number (which is parsed as `NaN`):

```
"a" == true
// Case 7 (true --> 1)
// =>"a" == 1
// Case 5 ("a" --> NaN)
// => NaN == 1
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to see how Javascripts works.

`"a"` is a string.
`true` is a boolean.

So `"a"` is not equal to `true`.

Doing `Boolean("a")`, is like to ask "Is `"a"` ?". This bizarre question will answer `true` if what you put in (so here `"a"`) is [implicitly something not null or empty].

You shouldn't use this `Boolean` function in this context, the result will never be what you think (`Boolean("false")` will return `true` for example)

See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/264037/6532640

Comment: The `===` operator is not the same as `==`. Using `==` will attempt to cast the types to make them the same. For example `"1" == true` returns `true`.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to talk about this; but yeah `"1"==true` is `true` ( `"a"==true` is `false`, comparing values), when `"1"===true` will be `false` (comparing values and types to say simple)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Boolean("a") is equal to asking if "a" == "a" so it will return true
console.log(Boolean("a"));

// "a" == true can't return true, because a string and a boolean can't be equal
console.log("a" == true);

// for the same reason this will return false too
console.log("true" == true);

// and this will return true
console.log("true" == true.toString());

//-----------------------------------------

// If we talk about numbers, there are different rules.
// In javascript you will be able to convert a string with 
// numbers to a number and vice versa 

// this is why "1" is equal to 1
console.log("1" == 1);

// considering the interest in trying to use every kind of
// variable in var, they described some basical rules
// for example adding a number to a string will work
// like every language

// this is why here you will obtain "11" as result
var one = "1";
console.log(one+1);

// in this case - doesn't work with strings, so our var one
// will be considered as an integer and the result will be 1
var one = "1";
console.log(one-1+1);
```