# Having confusion regarding how to pass value in a var through prompt

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var p=prompt("how old are you","");
if(p)
alert(p+" is your age");
else
alert("You dint entered any input or you have entered a non-integervalue");
</script>
```

This is my javascript code. Suppose i enter my age 0.

Then p=0 this implies the else part of the code will execute. But the code is executing the if part!

***Why is it happening?***

I'm new to Web-development , Please Help.

 **Thank You!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, why is "0" equal to false, but when tested by 'if' it is not false by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-when-tested-by-if-it-is-not-fals)

Comment: Because it returns a string of zero `"0"` not a number of `0`. only empty strings `""` get coerced into `false`

Comment: That's because your if condition is checking for any input. It doesn't know you are expecting a number or the amount. Check this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3rpmsoxh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt()` the result of the prompt, that means, parsing the string result to an *integer*

Now, if the input is `"0"`, it is parsed to `0`, and `0 == false`.

Thus the "else" condition would take place, as required.

Also, if a non-integer string is entered, such as alphabets, the result would be a `NaN` and the `else` part would occur

```
var p=parseInt(prompt("how old are you",""));
if(p) {
alert(p+" is your age");
}
else {
alert("You dint entered any input or you have entered a non-integervalue");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write this code :

```js
var p=prompt("how old are you","");
alert(typeof(p));
```

You will see that it is a string. `"0"` is a string, so it will be evaluated to `true` as it is **not empty** or **null**.

So, parse it to a number before doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure the prompt input is number, you should use isNaN function to check the input.

```
    var p=prompt("how old are you",""); 
    if(!isNaN(p)) alert(p+" is your age"); 
    else alert("You dint entered any input or you have entered a non-integervalue");
```