# Why !"0" == "0" is true?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with JavaScript and I had this bug, the cause was that "0" and !"0" entered in the "then" sentence. When I tried in a console I saw:

```
!"0" == "0" -> true
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Because `(!("0" == "0")) != ((!"0") == "0")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, why is "0" equal to false, but when tested by 'if' it is not false by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-when-tested-by-if-it-is-not-fals)

Comment: Why does this matter? Is this an actual problem in code? Did you see this somewhere else? If so, what was the context? Didn't they give an explanation for this seemingly useless bit of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!"0"` converts the string `"0"` into a boolean, and takes its negation. So since `"0"` is truthy (the only falsy string is the empty string), its negation is the boolean value `false`. So to be clear:

`!"0"` is converted to `false`.

Since we are comparing the boolean `false` with the string `"0"`, javascript **will convert both values to numbers**. See the table in [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) to see which types, when compared, are converted to what. You'll note that for a boolean and string, both are changed to numbers and then compared.

So wrapping up, we have `!"0"`, which evaluates to `false`. Then we compare that to the other string: `"0"`. Because one is a boolean, and the other a string, they are converted to numbers. The number conversion for `false` is `0`, and the number conversion for `"0"` is `0`, which are equal. Thus we get the result you see.

Comment: "0" is not truthy, "0" == false -> true, but your answer is correct

Comment: But why !"0" evaluates to false?

Comment: `"0"` is truthy, but being truthy *is not the same as being `==` to `true`*. When you compare it directly to a boolean, as before, they are converted to numbers. So `"0" -> 0` and `false -> 0` and `0 === 0`, so you get true.

Comment: Mind blown, I always think that truthy is exactly being equal to true.

Comment: I guess you could say `x` is truthy *if and only if* `Boolean(x) === true`, where `Boolean` is the built-in javascript function. So then you could note that `Boolean("0")` does return `true`. Pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

One would say, its javascript. There is a logical explanation:

- `!"0"` evaluates to `false`
- `"0"` will be casted to `0` which is equal to `false`

Since you are now comparing `false` and `false`, they are both the same. Your comparison has to be true.

Comment: Why !"0" evaluates to false?

Answer (score 0):

This is why JavaScript coercion is tricky and plays very handy part specifically in case of **0** number which is 99% the bug cause.

- When Equality (==) comparison is applied on two values e.g **x == y** by default comparison value is checked from L->R (left to rigth).
- So In your case before Loose **(==)** equality is checked the **!** (negation is applied) which results ****!"0"** -> false.**
- Now comes the coercion part:  According to ECMAScript **ecma-262 specs** it states

  - If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ! ToNumber(x) == y.

    **OR**
  - If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ! ToNumber(y).

Which means if either of the value is in Boolean like in our case

-> **false == "0"**

-> Number(false) == "0"

-> Number(false) == Number("0")

-> 0 == 0 // Results into truthy values;

```
Therefore:
!"0" == "0" -> true
```

Answer (score -1):

`!"0"` will convert `"0"` to `false` and then `false` is `==` to `"0"` because they will both be converted to the integer 0.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7615326/4949918