# false=="0" results as true, but !!"0" results as true

Tags: javascript, boolean, expression, ecmascript-5

Today while reading a blog on JavaScript, I came across the below example which seems odd to me. Please clarify.

As per my JavaScript knowledge `!!"0"` results `true`

But, the below statement result seems odd to me, and even I executed it in console which also returned `true`

`false == "0" //results true`

My interpretation of this statement is as below

`"0"` is treated as `true`, so the above statement can be rewritten as `false == true`, which must be resulted as `false`, but I am getting `true` as result. Please clarify.

Comment: info you may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-when-tested-by-if-it-is-not-fals

Comment: `("0" == true) === false`

Comment: As answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-when-tested-by-if-it-is-not-fals, the reason is because when you explicitly do "0" == false, both sides are being converted to numbers, and then the comparison is performed.

Answer (score 3):

When using `==`, `"0"` is first type casted to it's number value, `0`. And `0 == false`.

When doing `!!"0"`, it is not casted, and simply converts the string to a boolean, and since any non-empty string is truthy, it equals to `true`.