# In javascript, is "0" falsy or truthy?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

In JS, it's not clear if '0' is truthy or falsy.
So, we have :

Boolean('0') == true, because it's a non-empty string.
But: `('0' == false)`

The brain-itching starts from here :
`(!'0' == false)`

And then so...
`('0' == !'0')  // What ?!?`

At the beginning, willing to store a websocket stream into a Mysql DB, I needed to convert each field from a string to its primitive type.
Using the double NOT operator to get booleans didn't produce the result I was expecting :
`(!!"1" == true) && (!!"0" == true)`

Having my input string s, I finally came up with this working solution :
`!!+s`

Or this one : `(s == '1')`

Comment: why not check the value according to the table's description? for numbers use `isFinite` or the stronger `Number.isFinite`.

Comment: try '!0' instead of !'0'.  With !'0' you're saying; the inverse of the string literal '0' which is indeed false.

Comment: Non-empty strings are truthy, so `"0"` is truthy since it's a string with contents. The number `0` is falsy though (using `== false` isn't a valid way to check if something is truthy/falsy, `!!` or `Boolean` is better)

Comment: `'0' == false` due to type coercion (I think)

Comment: any non-empty string is truthy value

Comment: See [In JavaScript, why is "0" equal to false, but when tested by 'if' it is not false by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615214/in-javascript-why-is-0-equal-to-false-but-when-tested-by-if-it-is-not-fals)

Comment: Conclusion: never use `==` in JavaScript, but only `===`  That should stop the itching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Is `'0'` truthy?

`'0'` is truthy, because non-empty strings are truthy

`'0' == false` is truthy, because `==` operator converts both operands to number first and then try to compare them. `'0'` is converted to `0` and `false` is converted to `0`

`(!'0' == false)` - here `!'0'` is the same as `!true` because a non-empty string is truthy

`('0' == !'0')` - first `!'0'` is converted to `!true` then `false` and then both operands are converted to number so `0 == 0` is true

If you want intuitive behaviour don't use `==`. Use `===` instead

**Conclusion:**

`'0'` is falsy, but `==` operator converts strings to numbers

### About `(!!"1" == true) && (!!"0" == true)`:

Isn't it easier to use:

```
const s = '1'
const boolean = s === '1'
```

?

Comment: Thank you for giving me what I was missing : an explanation !

Comment: `const s = '1'
const b = !!+s`