# JavaScript: Why is NaN !== NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

What is the reasoning? I believe this is the only value not equal to itself in JavaScript.

Comment: Note that `NaN == NaN` also returns false.

Comment: Because the spec says so? Your believe is correct.

Comment: i've found this to be more helpful than the "Why is NaN not equal to NaN" question suggested by SO editors above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values ... in a nutshell, because NaN contains information about what something isn't (rather than what it is), NaN (e.g. sqrt(-2)) can never said to be definitely equal to NaN (e.g. sqrt(-3))

Answer (score 1):

NaN isn't equal to NaN

Use the IsNaN function to check it

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976721/is-nan-equals-to-nan)

Comment: They question is asking *why*, not what alternatives there are to `!==` for this.