# I can't get the alert to work properly

Tags: javascript

```
set("mean",total/weight);
if (mean = "NaN") {
    alert("Error! Please use NUMBERS only");
}
```

i want the alert to only run when the result is NaN, the calculation works without the if statement so i know that is not the problem.

Comment: Use the comparison operator `==`, not `=`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function for the comparison:

```
if(isNaN(mean)){
    alert("Error! Please use NUMBERS only");
}
```

Comment: the calculation runs but now the alert pops up no matter what

Comment: nevermind, using a way to get around this. thanks though

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `mean = "NaN"`, with a *single equals* **sets the value** of `mean`. The if statement will then check the "trueness" of the value "NaN" which will evaluate to true. That is, your `if(mean = "NaN")` will first set `mean` to the literal string `"NaN"`, and then test `if("NaN")`.

Use a *double equals* (`mean == "NaN"`) for equality comparison, and *triple equals* (`mean === "NaN"`) for type and equality comparison.

However, `mean == "NaN"` will always return `false` because [`NaN` is not the literal string `"NaN"` but a special value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976721/is-nan-equals-to-nan). Use `isNaN(mean)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (mean = "NaN") {
```

to

```
if (mean == "NaN") {
```

in the first u set a value into a var, in the second u do a logical comparison

Answer (score 0):

You are assgining a string `"NaN"` to `mean`, not comparison.

Also you can't use `mean === NaN` to check, because compare to `NaN` always return false.

To check whether is a `NaN`, you have to use **[isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)** function.

```
if (isNaN(mean)) {
    alert("Error! Please use NUMBERS only");
}
```