# Comparing NaN in javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, if we multiply a string with number we get `NaN`:

```
 console.log("manas" * 5); // result is NaN
```

Why then does the following code result in `false` instead of `true`?

```
console.log("manas" * 5 == NaN)  // results false
```

Comment: Instead of padding out your text to bypass the quality filter, how about you actually *add in a question*? You managed to format the code just fine, it is the rest of your question body that is the problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `isNaN` function instead.

```
console.log(isNaN("manas" * 5));
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

NaN, not a number, is a special type value used to denote an unrepresentable value. With JavaScript, NaN can cause some confusion, starting from its typeof and all to the way the comparison is handled.

Several operations can lead to NaN as the result.
Because there are many ways to represent a NaN, it makes sense that one NaN will not be equal to another NaN.

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` is a special numeric value which is not equal to anything including itself. To properly test for `NaN` you need to use [isNaN](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4) function.

From specification:

> Returns true if the argument coerces to NaN, and otherwise returns false.

Here is also useful note from the same [ECMAScript section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4):

> A reliable way for ECMAScript code to test if a value X is a NaN is an expression of the form `X !== X`. The result will be true if and only if X is a NaN.

Comment: NaN is also not equal to itself NaN == NaN  // false

Answer (score 0):

NaN compares unequal (via ==, !=, ===, and !==) to any other value -- including to another NaN value.  Use Number.isNaN() or isNaN() to most clearly determine whether a value is NaN.  Or perform a self-comparison: NaN, and only NaN, will compare unequal to itself.
[Testing against NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not that smart - when either side of the `==` operator is `Nan`, the whole thing evaluates as false (similar to how if leftside of `||` is `false`, it doesn't bother looking at right side)

So, even `Nan == Nan` will return false.

Here's a good article on Nan behaviour

http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2014/05/the-curious-case-of-javascript-nan.html

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript,

```
NaN == NaN    //always results false.
```

(self comparison of NaN to itself is always false in javascript)

refer:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

also see [Is NaN equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976721/is-nan-equals-to-nan)