# Does `always returns unordered result` meaning `returns false`

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm reading about `NaN` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) and it says that:

> A comparison with a NaN always returns an **unordered** result even when
>   comparing with itself.

I'm confused about the word *unordered*. For practical reasons, does it mean that comparison will always evaluate to `false`? It seems to be the case:

```
// all statemens below evaluate to false

NaN === NaN
NaN > NaN
NaN < NaN

NaN > 3
NaN < 3
NaN === 3
```

Comment: yes. all above returns false. NaN cannot be used in comparisions.

Comment: It would help if you provide a link to the statement so it can be evaluated in context. It seems like a confusing way to say "*Comparisons with NaN always return false*".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976721/is-nan-equal-to-nan

Comment: @RobG, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When comparing two floating point numbers `a` and `b`, there will be exactly 1 of 4 outcomes:

- `a` is less than `b`
- `a` is equal to `b`
- `a` is greater than `b`
- `a` and `b` are unordered.

The IEEE754 spec states that `a` and `b` are unordered when either `a` or `b` is a NaN (which includes the case when both `a` and `b` are NaN).

In most languages the first 3 have their own predicates (typically `<`, `==`, `>`). The unordered case does not, but can be tested by checking that all the others are false.

Comment: thanks for you help. Just wondering whether you've read the spec? It's not free as I understand

Comment: I managed to download a copy through my old university library, which had an IEEE subscription. It's quite easy to find draft versions online, which are fairly similar to the final spec.