# Jquery - Calculating height sum of elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

To calculate height sum of elements and apply as "min-height" on .body div I am using:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
  var a = $("body").outerHeight();
  var b = $(".header").outerHeight(true);
  var c = $(".footer").outerHeight(true);
  var d = $(".bottom").outerHeight(true);
  $(".body").css("min-height", a - b - c - d);
}).trigger("resize");
```

It works fine if all elements exists on html, but if one element missing it's broken.

Good - https://jsfiddle.net/0ggr3ptv/1/

Bad - https://jsfiddle.net/oed11Lzm/1/ .bottom div is missing.

How to exclude missing elements or let them be 0?

Using jQuery 3.1.1 and .bottom div becomes undefined. How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var d = $(".bottom").outerHeight(true) || 0;
```

Instead of

```
var d = $(".bottom").outerHeight(true);
```

to make the default value set to 0. There is more information that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540397/convert-nan-to-0-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is number or not using [isNAN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) 
 `d = isNaN(d) ? 0 : d;`

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oed11Lzm/2/