# Output of Text Box Displays NaN on Calculations

Tags: javascript, html

I have a situation where a few calculations were to be performed. I have created a few lines of formula to calculate the scenarios in `Calc()` function.

The calculations are working fine but I am having issue with the `NaN`output. When I do not input anything and click on the `Calculate` button, the text box shows an output of `NaN`. I understand that `NaN` indicates Not A Number but I am helpless in solving this issue.

I would want an output of 0.00 instead of `NaN`. Need help on this.

```js
function Calc() {
    let arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    let tot = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let radios = document.getElementsByName("group" + (i + 1));
        for (let j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
            let radio = radios[j];
            if (radio.value == "Yes" && radio.checked) {
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
            }
         }
    }

    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
    var stdHour = ((tot * 1.15) / 3600);
    document.getElementById('stdHour').value = stdHour.toFixed(4);
    var earnHour = ((tot * 1.15) / 3600) * document.getElementById('unitNum').value;
    document.getElementById('earnHour').value = earnHour.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById('hc').value = ((earnHour / 19.8) * document.getElementById('numDays').value).toFixed(3);
    var earnDays = ((document.getElementById('unitNum').value / ((document.getElementById('numHeadC').value / stdHour) * 6.6)) / 3);
    document.getElementById('days').value = earnDays.toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById('perday').value = ((document.getElementById('numHeadC').value / stdHour * 6.6) * 3).toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById('hcperday').value = ((document.getElementById('output').value / 19.8) * stdHour).toFixed(3);
}
```

```html
<h3>
    <B>Extreme Temperature (Cold Temp)</B>
</h3>
<table class="table2" style="width:60%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <label id="group5">
            <td>ATE Labview RF Testing Extreme</td>
         <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="153" align="center" name="qty" id="qty5" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/></td>
         <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group5" value="Yes" checked="checked"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group5" value="No"></td>
        </label>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <label id="group6">
            <td>User Interface Extreme</td>
         <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="0" align="center" name="qty" id="qty6" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/></td>
         <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group6" value="Yes"></td>
            <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group6" value="No" checked="checked"></td>
        </label>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <label id="group7">
            <td>Mic Talk Internal Extreme</td>
         <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="68" align="center" name="qty" id="qty7" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/></td>
         <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group7" value="Yes" checked="checked"></td>
           <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group7" value="No"></td>
        </label>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <label id="group8">
             <td>Mic Talk External Extreme</td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="53" align="center" name="qty" id="qty8" maxlength="4" size="4" readonly="readonly"/></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group8" value="Yes" checked="checked"></td>
             <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group8" value="No"></td>
          </label>
     </tr>

     <tr>
         <label id="group9">
             <td>Desense Test</td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="50" align="center" name="qty" id="qty9" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group9" value="Yes" checked="checked"></td>
             <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group9" value="No"></td>
         </label>
     </tr>

     <tr>
         <label id="group10">
             <td>Tx Stability</td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="43" align="center" name="qty" id="qty10" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group10" value="Yes" checked="checked"></td>
             <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group10" value="No"></td>
          </label>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <label id="group11">
             <td>Microphonic Test</td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty11" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group11" value="Yes" checked="checked"></td>
             <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group11" value="No"></td>
         </label>
     </tr>
</table>
<br><br>

<!---Number of units--->
<br><br>
<table class="resultsTbl">

  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">
      <h4>Enter The Number of Units : <input type="text" id="unitNum"></h4>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" align="center" /> Seconds</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Standard Hour</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="stdHour" id="stdHour" align="center" /> Hour</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Earn Hour</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="earnHour" id="earnHour" /> Hour</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<br><br>
<!--Scenario 1-->
<table class="resultsTbl">

  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="scenario1"><input type="checkbox" value="select" align="center" id="check1"> Scenario 1</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="cent">Calculate The Number of Head Count When Days Are Fixed</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Number of Days</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" id="numDays" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Head Count</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="hc" id="hc" /> Per Shift</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br><br>
<!--End of Form For Scenario 1-->
<table class="resultsTbl">

  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="scenario2"><input type="checkbox" value="select" align="center" id="check2"> Scenario 2</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="cent">Calculate The Number of Days When Head Counts Are Fixed</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Number of Head Count</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" id="numHeadC" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Number of Days</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="days" id="days" /> Days</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Output Per Day</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="perday" id="perday" /> Per Day</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br><br>

<table class="resultsTbl">

  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="scenario3"><input type="checkbox" value="select"> Scenario 3</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="cent">Calculate The Number of Head Counts According to The Daily Output</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Daily Output</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" id="output" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>HC 2</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="hcperday" id="hcperday" /> Per Shift</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br><br><br>
<form align="center">
  <div id="button"><button type="button" name="button1" onClick="Calc()" class="button button1">Calculate</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can check the text box value is empty or not before passing it to the calculation and the `if(empty){ document.getElementById("total".value = 0.00} else { //your claculation }.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert NaN to 0 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540397/convert-nan-to-0-in-javascript)

Comment: `if(Element.value !== '')`

Answer (score 0):

You can give your value a default value. i.e

```
var earnDays = ((document.getElementById('unitNum').value / ((document.getElementById('numHeadC').value / stdHour) * 6.6)) / 3) || 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The result NaN has come from **division by zero** at this line [ just did an indentation to spot easily ]

```
var earnDays = ((
                  document.getElementById('unitNum').value / 
                   ((document.getElementById('numHeadC').value / stdHour) *6.6) 
                 )
           / 3 );
```

In chrome devtools, You can find this by putting a break point and then selecting the expression by your mouse to see the value
[image]

So, you have to code the logic to find the earnDays when document.getElementById('numHeadC').value is '' (emty string) which converts to 0.

like this as you wanted to be 0.0 :

```
var earnDays = 0.0;
if (document.getElementById('numHeadC').value)
    earnDays = ((document.getElementById('unitNum').value / ((document.getElementById('numHeadC').value / stdHour) * 6.6)) / 3);
```