# How is the nullish coalescing operator (??) different from the logical OR operator (||) in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, logical-or, ecmascript-2020, nullish-coalescing

ES2020 introduced the **nullish coalescing operator (`??`)** which returns the right operand if the left operand is null or undefined. This functionality is similar to the **logical OR operator (`||`)**. For example, the below expressions return the same results.

```
const a = undefined
const b = "B"

const orOperator = a || b
const nullishOperator = a ?? b
  
console.log({ orOperator, nullishOperator })
```

result:

```
{
    orOperator:"B",
    nullishOperator:"B"
}
```

So how is the **nullish operator** different and what is its use case?

Comment: One difference is the way it handles `false`

Comment: `a || b === a ? a : b` , `a ?? b === a != null ? a : b`

Comment: One doesn't have to look further than the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

Comment: *"For example, the below expressions return the same results."* You can find lots of examples where specific values produce the same results with different operators. E.g. `0 + 0`, `0 - 0`, `0 * 0` all produce `0`, yet I hope no one would argue that those operators do different things. If you want to understand the difference between operators, looking at a single example is not enough.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `||` operator evaluates to the right-hand side if and only if the left-hand side is a **[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)** value.

The `??` operator (null coalescing) evaluates to the right-hand side if and only if the left-hand side is either `null` or `undefined`.

`false`, `0`, `NaN`, `""` (empty string) are for example considered falsy, but maybe you actually want those values. In that case, the `??` operator is the right operator to use.

Answer (score -2):

If you are intended to provide a default value to a number that may potentially be NaN, do this:

```
a = a || 0

// Not this
// a = a ?? 0
```

Also see [convert NaN to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540397/convert-nan-to-0-in-javascript).

Explanation:

Both operators are common for providing a default value for a variable. A situation for handling possible NaN value may mark some difference:

```
let userAge = null

let age1 = userAge || 21
let age2 = userAge ?? 21
console.log(age1) // 21
console.log(age2) // 21
```

```
let userAge = parseFloat(null)

let age1 = userAge || 21
let age2 = userAge ?? 21
console.log(age1) // 21
console.log(age2) // NaN
```

If you wish to let a value with possible NaN value fall back to a default value, choose `||`. Double question mark aka the nullish operator `??` doesn't do the fallback here.