# What does "??" do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I saw this a while ago, and I think it may have some use for something, but I don't remember at all what it does. does it do anything in javaScript? If so, may a example be provided.

`??`

Comment: Try reading [this](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es-next/javascript-nullish-coalescing-operator/)

Comment: Search for null coalescing - it's a new syntax.

Comment: Related: [How is the nullish coalescing operator (??) different from the logical OR operator (||) in ECMAScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65022531) and [When should I use ?? (nullish coalescing) vs || (logical OR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61480993)