# What is the meaning of " ?? " in conditional operator in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, conditional-operator

I have been encountering with this conditional operator,

phone={this.props.projectDetails?.agency?.phone ?? this.props.projectDetails.phone  }

I wanted to use Phone number that is given in agency?.phone but at some point we didn’t had phone number in agency so we were using projectDetail's phone so overcome this issue.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the nullish coalescing operator (??) different from the logical OR operator (||) in ECMAScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022531/how-is-the-nullish-coalescing-operator-different-from-the-logical-or-operat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's Nullish coalescing operator and in your case  exactly equal to this :

```
phone={this.props.projectDetails?.agency?.phone ? this.props.projectDetails.agency.phone : this.props.projectDetails.phone }
```

Comment: That's not true, ternary operator's [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values are different than the Nuillish coalescing which [works exactly like the logical OR operator, except you will get the right side value when the left side value is `undefined` or `null`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-the-question-mark-works-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Nullish coalescing operator means If is null or undefined you will render projectDetails.phone prop

Answer (score 0):

In case if we don't have any else condition ,  use  **Nullish coalescing operator (??)**

> this.props.projectDetails?.agency?.phone (if it has value) ?? (then show) this.props.projectDetails.phone

..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing

Comment: this.props.projectDetails?.agency?.phone (if it has value then show it) ?? (Otherwise show this) this.props.projectDetails.phone