# How to remove or simply substitute Nan with 0?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 inputs.

When I put 2 in the n1 input, the second input says 4.

But if I don't put anything in the first (n1), the second inpout (n2) says `NaN`.

How remove this `NaN`?

```html
<td><input type="number" value=0 id="n1" oninput="test()"/> <br/><br/></td>

<td></td>

<td><input type="text" value=0 id="result" readonly/><br><br></td>
```

```js
function test () {
  var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);

  var oper = document.getElementById('selector1').value;
  var oper2 = document.getElementById('selector2').value;

  if (oper === 'm' && oper2 === 's') {
    document.getElementById('result').value = n1 * 60;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code for `test()`

Comment: Where is the javascript code that does this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert NaN to 0 in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540397/convert-nan-to-0-in-javascript)

Comment: function test()
            {
                var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);


                var oper = document.getElementById('selector1').value;
    var oper2 = document.getElementById('selector2').value;


                if(oper === 'm' && oper2 === 's')
                {
                    document.getElementById('result').value = n1*60;
                }
}

Comment: is this please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
```

to this one:

```
var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value) || 0;
```

This will give `n1` a value of 0 if you leave its input field blank.

Comment: instead of the value 0 is it possible to make it show nothing?

Comment: Yes. Change `document.getElementById('result').value = n1 * 60;` to `document.getElementById('result').value = (n1 * 60) || "";`

Comment: Could you explain to me why it works to just put it there?

var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value) || "";

This because don't work?

Comment: If you put it after `var n1 = ...` then `n1` would get the value `""`. When you multiply `""` by 60 you get 0. You need to set the input's value itself to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your calculation in an if statement checking to make sure n1 is a number before running, you can make sure that the function does not run if no value is set.

```
<td> <input type="number" value=0 id="n1" oninput="test()"/> <br/><br/> </td>

<td> </td>

<td> <input type="text" value=0 id="result"  readonly /><br><br> </td>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function test() {
    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
    var oper = document.getElementById('selector1').value;
    var oper2 = document.getElementById('selector2').value;
    if (oper === 'm' && oper2 === 's') {
      if (isNaN(n1) != true){
        document.getElementById('result').value = n1 * 60;
      }
    }
}
</script>
```