# What is IEEE-754?

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

MDN puts the isNaN() function in a nutshell:

> "is this value, when coerced to a numeric value, an IEEE-754 'Not A
>   Number' value?"

What is **IEEE-754** ?

P.S. I have read and researched quite a bit about `isNaN` , and have seen **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115548/why-is-isnannull-false-in-js)**, thread too.  I just don't know what IEEE-754 is supposed to mean.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean “What is IEEE-754”? Have you Googled this?

Comment: There’s even an [ieee-754 tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ieee-754/info) on SO.

Comment: When in doubt, read [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), and when in great doubt, read [the spec](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4610935&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fstamp%2Fstamp.jsp%3Ftp%3D%26arnumber%3D4610935).

Comment: Thanks guys , will keep that in mind .

Comment: Please can we add the functionality to SO that takes the title of a question and submits it to a search engine thereby showing potentially matching answers before submission?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ucoXVoGwFMLDoAPE4I-wBw&gws_rd=ssl#q=what+is+ieee+754 google page for your title

Comment: @KevinDTimm lookup the subject on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and post your suggestion there if it's not a feature request already.

Comment: @Boaz - going there now

Comment: While strictly correct, the mention of IEEE-754 is something of a red herring. *NaN* represents a generic "this is not a number" value in much the same way that *undefined* means the value is undefined even though it has been assigned the *undefined* value. Read the [*spec*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-isnan-number), essentially *isNaN* returns false if a value can be converted to a number value other than NaN. Otherwise it returns true.

Comment: @RobG thanks .... :)

Comment: If you're interested in the long answer, read this: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks for contributing .. will bookmark that.

Answer (score 3):

[IEEE 754](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/) is the Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic by The Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers. It describes how computers deal with numbers.