# Why isNaN([3]) is false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I use Chrome browser 60.x, and test the code `isNaN([3])`.
The result is `false`, but I cannot understand it.

`[3]` is an Array, and it is not empty.
I think `[3]` is array object, and it is not an number.

Otherwise the result of `isNaN(["ABC"])` is `true`.
And another result of `isNaN([1,2,3])` is `true`.
So I guess javascript engine is force changing array to number which the array has a single element.

Please let me know what is happened `isNaN` function for array parameter.

ref1: [Why is isNaN(null) == false in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115548/why-is-isnannull-false-in-js) 
ref2: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

---

[EDIT] Thank you everyone for answering.

I understand javascript parsed the value implicitly before comparison.

And I found a useful link while reading Nina Scholz's answer.
The comparison table : http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: In title you say that `isNaN([3]) = false`, in question you say that it is true... What is it?

Comment: Strong typing versus weak typing.  In. Some languages, implicit conversions are allowed for convenience.  In others, all must be explicit for reliability.

Comment: While `[3]` is deterministic `[1,2,3]` is not and JS implicitly makes use of this fact by applying type coercion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `isNaN` it tries to parse your input value into the `number` and then checks if it is `NaN` or not.

**See some examples.**

For an array with one item, the `Number()` function returns an object, which actually hold the first item as a value (see `console.log`). For many items it returns `NaN`, so you get `isNaN`'s result -> `true`.

```js
const a = new Number([3]);
console.log(`a is ${a}`);
console.log(`isNaN(a) - ${isNaN(a)}`);


const b = new Number([3,4,5]);
console.log(`b is ${b}`);
console.log(`isNaN(b) - ${isNaN(b)}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the rules for [equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness), the array is converted, first with `toString` and then to a number for checking.

```js
console.log(isNaN([3]));
console.log(isNaN('3')); // convert with toString to a primitive
console.log(isNaN(3));   // convert to number
```

Comment: This rather goes under the [standard for `isNaN`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isnan-number) ..? (Appeared to be pretty complex.)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript works in the following way: It tries to convert the object to `integer` if the argument of the function is expected to be an integer. For example running

```
x = increment([3])
```

will result in `x = 4`. Therefore running

```
isNan([3])
```

will result in `false`, since `[3]` gets converted to `3` and `3` is a number. Similarly, `["ABC"]` cannot get converted to `integer`, therefore `isNaN(["ABC"]) = true`. Also, javascript fails to convert `[1,2,3]` to a number, since there are three numbers in array, therefore

```
isNaN([1,2,3]) = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, as a shorthand in Javascript,, arrays containing only one number are considered castable to the number it contains. You can see this behavior with `==`

```
3 == [3] // returns true
```

Additionaly, that's also why `[0]` is a falsy value, whereas `[n]` with `n` not zero is a truthy value, an horrible potential source of bugs.

```
[0] == false // returns true 
[1] == false // returns false
```

Comment: you can use triple equals to include type-checking as well. 3 === [3] // false

Comment: exactly, my point was about a implicit cast that occurs, and these casts occurs when you use double-equals only.  that's why I don't think it is relevant to include it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

So as we know
    `isNaN([3]) // returns false`

A workaround to test number vs array with number

```
Number([3]) === [3] //returns false 
Number(3) === 3 // returns true
```

Remember that === means matching the values ***and*** type