# Why isNaN(true) ( or (isNaN(false) ) is returning false?

Tags: javascript

Just a simple question...

Why this:
`isNaN(true)`
or this: 
`isNaN(false)`
return `false` ?

I can understand that `false` is evaluate to `0` and `true` to `1` or something...

But is it not the purpose of `isNaN(...)` to return false only if a variable or a value is "exactly" a number ?

Comment: isNaN return true only if the value **Is Not a Number**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: "The function should be interpreted as answering the question, "is this value, when coerced to a numeric value, an IEEE-754 'Not A Number' value?"" Meaning, the underlying value is still a number, 0 or 1.

Comment: While the questions are subtly different, the answers of [Why is IsNaNnull == false in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115548/why-is-isnannull-false-in-js) go over  why thinking `isNaN` is a suitable replacement for a `isNumeric` function is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

As you think, they return false, because `isNaN` first coerces its argument into a Number, and then it returns whether the argument is NaN.

`Number(true)` is `1` and `Number(false)` is `0`, so neither of them is NaN.

To perform a stricter check, and avoid implicit coercion, call [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) instead:

Both `Number.isNaN(true)` and `Number.isNaN(false)` returns `true`.